# How do I debug Node.js applications?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

How do I debug a Node.js server application?

Right now I'm mostly using *alert debugging* with print statements like this:

```
sys.puts(sys.inspect(someVariable));
```

There must be a better way to debug. I know that [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) has a command-line debugger. Is this debugger available for Node.js as well?

Comment: You can use [Locus](https://github.com/alidavut/locus) for command line injection.

Comment: If you want to debug with the traditional IDE appoach, use vscode
use vscode
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egBJ0cd0GLM

Comment: I have found this article very interesting, and it works for me just fine: [**Debugging Node.js with Chrome DevTools**](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.68uvlrpco). Hope it helps :)

Comment: "alert debugging" :)

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to run nod with `--inspect-brk` INSTEAD OF `--inspect` if you want to debug the actual server code at load time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596138

Comment: Check this blog: https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: I found a good article for How To Debug NodeJs App: 
https://idkblogs.com/node/418/How-To-Debug-NodeJs-App-in-VS-Code-

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) debugger released as part of the Google [Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/) can be used to debug Node.js scripts. A detailed explanation of how this works can be found in the [Node.js GitHub wiki](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger).

Comment: I'm interested, after the presentation at Google IO that Paul Irish and Pavel did is it now possible to debug node.js straight to Chrome Developer Tools without the need for eclipse?

Comment: +1 Worked very well for me. Using a fresh Eclipse 3.x, x64 version on Mac OS X. The installation instructions are well written as well. Thank you.

Comment: Also comes within Nodeclipse http://www.nodeclipse.org/ (with some Node.js related bugs fixed)

Comment: My entry into this arena is trepanjs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/trepanjs). It has all of the goodness of the node debugger, but conforms better to gdb. It also has more features and commands like syntax highlighting, more extensive online help, and smarter evaluation. See https://github.com/rocky/trepanjs/wiki/Cool-things for some of its cool features.

Comment: Sadly the explanation seems not to exist on the new wiki page.

Comment: The feature is currently available in the nightly versions. Check out here for instructions: `https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.fitvuaumt`

Comment: Does not work with Netbeans!
As node.js changed the option from --debug[-brk] to --inspect[-brk] the only workaround was to add a npm script for quick debugging.

Have in package.json something like:
"scripts": {
        "debug": "node --inspect-brk=9292 main.js"
  }

Answer (score 1308):

[node-inspector](http://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) could save the day! Use it from any browser supporting [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Breakpoints, profiler, livecoding, etc... It is really awesome.

Install it with:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

Then run:

```
node-debug app.js
```

Comment: Wish node-inspector was active. The profiling component needs to get some love.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/ketamynx/node-codein instead of node-inspector's console. It can display objects.

Comment: For me breakpoints do not work in node-inspector. Do they for you guys? Any additional mambo-jumbo to make them work?

Comment: It used to work for me, but with node v0.8.3 it doesn't work :(

Comment: @jayarjo is it because your program is exiting before breakpoints can be attached? Have you tried running your code with `node --debug-brk"? This breaks on the first line of the code

Comment: Unfortunately for me, node-inspector doesn't work with the latest versions of Node.js and it hasn't supported logging to the browser console since v0.1. node-codein was just buggy. So, I wrote my own module to help with debugging by allowing you to dump objects and such out to your web browser console. I thought it may be of use to someone else: [node-monkey](https://github.com/jwarkentin/node-monkey). Plus it works in both Firefox AND Chrome.

Comment: Since this was such an apparently amazing and popular tool, surely the fact that the original author has admitted they no longer have the resources to maintain it wouldn't be a problem as the open source community could pick it up?

Comment: I'm using node-inspector with node 0.10 and it works as expected.  
I do it in Ubuntu 13.

Comment: Now inspector is now actively maintained by StrongLoop and is working again with the latest version (0.3) yay! Announcement here: http://blog.strongloop.com/announcing-a-new-and-improved-node-js-debugger/

Comment: if you get an INUSE error try changing the port the inspector runs on: --web-port=8181

Comment: Debugging both client and server on the same window. What else a web developer wants? This is perfect.

Comment: I have to echo the comments above and say that this tool is far, FAR better than what I was expecting. Definitely give it a go if you haven't tried it before and don't yet have a proper IDE sorted. I've just picked up Node and this is a great tool - works fine with the latest version under Windows (v0.10.31 as of today).

Comment: Is it possible to attach/deattach this debugger during runtime? I guess not, but it would be handy to debug minor issues in production apps without taking them down or running them under the debugger constantly.

Comment: For most people asking this question, including the OP, this answer should be the accepted answer.  It is an outstanding alternative to "alert-debugging" and I've used it a crap-ton with much success :D

Comment: Yes the rumours about it's death are exaggerated. Those comments ought to be removed because it made me disbelieve the answer and waste some more time.

Comment: As of Node 6.3 theres a built in node inspector, please see my answer for details...

Comment: *"Since version 6.3, Node.js provides a buit-in DevTools-based debugger which mostly deprecates Node Inspector, see e.g. [this blog post](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27) to get started. The built-in debugger is developed directly by the V8/Chromium team and provides certain advanced features (e.g. long/async stack traces) that are too difficult to implement in Node Inspector."* - says the node inspector repo

Answer (score 794):

### Debugging

- [Joyent's Guide](http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/debug)
- [Debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)
- [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs#_debugging-your-node-application)
- [Cloud9](https://docs.c9.io/running_and_debugging_code.html)
- [Brackets](https://github.com/adobe-research/theseus)

### Profiling

1. `node --prof ./app.js`
2. `node --prof-process ./the-generated-log-file`

### Heapdumps

- [node-heapdump with Chrome Developer Tools](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump)

### Flamegraphs

- [0x](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/0x)
- [jam3/devtool](https://github.com/jam3/devtool) then [Chrome Developer Tools Flame Charts](https://youtu.be/g0g4ML4nhPg)
- [Dtrace](http://dtrace.org/) and [StackVis](https://github.com/joyent/node-stackvis) — [Only supported on SmartOS](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/)
- [clinicjs](https://clinicjs.org/flame/)

### Tracing

- [Interactive Stack Traces with TraceGL](https://github.com/traceglMPL/tracegl)

### Logging

Libraries that output debugging information

- [Caterpillar](https://github.com/bevry/caterpillar)
- [Tracer](https://github.com/baryon/tracer)
- [scribbles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scribbles)

Libraries that enhance stack trace information

- [Longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn)

### Benchmarking

- [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html): `ab -n 100000 -c 1 http://127.0.0.1:9778/`
- [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk)

### Other

- [Trace](https://trace.risingstack.com)
- [Vantage](https://github.com/dthree/vantage)
- [Bugger](https://github.com/buggerjs/bugger)
- [Google Tracing Framework](http://google.github.io/tracing-framework)
- [Paul Irish's Guide](https://github.com/paulirish/automated-chrome-profiling)

### Legacy

These use to work but are no longer maintained or no longer applicable to modern node versions.

- https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler - replaced by built-in debugging
- https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent - replaced by node inspector
- https://nodetime.com/ - defunct

Comment: About Nodetime: for those who don't want to send their data to nodetime servers there's a local "alternative" (it's still based on nodetime), the `look` module, as pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864221/nodejs-memory-profiling

Comment: I don't find the cpu reports from nodetime very helpful:  
1. I just get a tree of methods, with no 'self' time.  
2. Seems like the tree branches are trimmed below a certain number of precentage.  
Those 2 makes it very difficult to undestand where the cpu spends most of its time.

Comment: npm install -g profiler complains about missing python on windows 7. I tried to set python=C:\Python34\, but this gives a crash.

Comment: The only profiler working out of the box is nodetime. But its cpu profiling stacktrace is unusable (it doesn't give enough details). Nodejs tools 4 msvc 2012 also have profiler, but it also has reported critical unfixed bug...

Comment: The only profiler that worked for me was `nprof` + `v8.log` from `node --prof`.

Comment: See the answer @hans posted below, should probably include Visual Studio Code here.

Comment: Definitely worth mentioning node clinic at this point: https://github.com/nearform/node-clinic

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to run nod with `--inspect-brk` INSTEAD OF `--inspect` if you want to debug the actual server code at load time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596138

Comment: The link to Node Inspector led to [another link](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27), which revealed that later versions of Node.js can be debugged more directly by specifying the `--inspect-brk ` arg when running node, and using Google Chrome as the debugger GUI.

Answer (score 214):

## Node has its own [built in](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js) GUI debugger as of version 6.3 (using Chrome's DevTools)

[image: Nodes builtin GUI debugger]

Simply pass the inspector flag and you'll be provided with a URL to the inspector:

```
node --inspect server.js
```

You can also break on the first line by passing `--inspect-brk` instead.

Comment: Not to discount the steps above, but just to share... I attempted to create a wrapper that is slightly more robust, as well as easier to install. See: https://github.com/jaridmargolin/inspect-process

Comment: @JaridR.Margolin Nice. I updated the answer to use that instead. A lot easier to setup and works better :)

Comment: This answer is currently at the bottom and it's the only one that has actually worked for me. This is flipping awesome!

Comment: For those using `nodemon` (if you're not, look it up!), use `nodemon --inspect` and then this tool to automatically open a new Chrome window: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj/related

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I threw up a video explaining this process at https://youtu.be/rtZKUnks6jI.

Comment: For node 6.x, use `node --inspect --debug-brk server.js` to automatically stop on the first line.

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to run nod with `--inspect-brk` INSTEAD OF `--inspect` if you want to debug the actual server code at load time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596138

Comment: For the client you need to Open chrome://inspect in a Chromium-based browser. More clients [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started#inspector-clients)

Answer (score 97):

Node.js version 0.3.4+ has built-in debugging support.

`node debug script.js`

Manual: http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Comment: Do you have any links to documentation of how to use it?

Comment: I don't have any docs. just updated to v0.3.5. put a line "debugger;" in your code which will act as break point. It works like ndb / gdb. after you do "node debug script.js" type help. u will see the command it support. p = print, l = list... so you don't need to type the full world

Comment: Note, under windows it's "node.exe --debug myscript.js" but it still don't work.

Comment: You probably have to change `--debug` to `debug` without the dashes. That's how I finally got it to work. It's confusing that `--debug` and `debug` do two different things.

Comment: How do you get the program to actually run? "r -> `app is already running...`", when i try to continue and i run into a statement that is trying to get input it drops me back at the debug prompt instead of letting me enter the input that is required.

Comment: debug has been deprecated.  you have to use `node inspect script.js` now

Comment: I really liked this debug tool, you could debug in a terminal without an IDE right? miss that

Answer (score 77):

***[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)*** will be my choice for debugging. No overhead of installing any tools or `npm install` stuff.
Just set the starting point of your app in package.json and VSCode will automatically create a configuration file inside your solution. It's build on [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), on which editors like Atom are built.

> VS Code gives similar debugging experience as you might have
>   had in other IDEs like VS, Eclipse, etc.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's cool but it has lag. That's why I do prefer Sublime ever.

Comment: but sublime doesn't have a debugger,and i think VS code is pretty fast too

Comment: I've a sublime license since 5 years ago. Since a few months ago I don't even install Sublime Text, just vscode. Out of the box has a lot of tools which I miss in Sublime (like the integrated terminal..).

Comment: always asking me for a config folder, it doesn't work out of the box

Comment: @carkod enable vs code _**auto attach**_ preference and use the vs code _**terminal**_ to start your script, ex node --inspect file-name.js

Answer (score 61):

I personally use [JetBrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) as it's the only JavaScript IDE that I've found which is great for both frontend and backend JavaScript.

It works on multiple OS's and has Node.js debugging built-in (as well as a ton of other stuff](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html).

My only 'issues'/wishlist items <del>are</del> **were**:

1. <del>It seems to be more resource hungry on Mac than Windows</del> It no longer seems an issue in version 6.
2. <del>It would be nice if it had Snippet support (like those of [Sublime Text 2](http://vimeo.com/41216114) - i.e. type 'fun' and tap 'tab' to put in a function.</del> See @WickyNilliams comment below - With Live Templates you also have snippet support.

Comment: webstorm does have snippet support BTW ;-) though they're known as "Live Templates" instead of snippets.

Comment: If you just want to debug a node.js app and already have an Intellij IDEA license you can just install the node.js plugin without having to buy the WebStorm license. Setting up a run/debug config is very easy once the plugin is installed.

Answer (score 46):

A lot of great answers here, but I'd like to add my view (based on how my approach evolved)

### Debug Logs

Let's face it, we all love a good `console.log('Uh oh, if you reached here, you better run.')` and sometimes that works great, so if you're reticent to move too far away from it at least add some bling to your logs with [Visionmedia's debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug).

### Interactive Debugging

As handy as console logging can be, to debug professionally you need to roll up your sleeves and get stuck in. Set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect scopes and variables to see what's causing that weird behaviour. As others have mentioned, [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector) really is the bees-knees. It does everything you can do with the built-in debugger, but using that familiar Chrome DevTools interface.
If, like me, you use **Webstorm**, then [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#d186741e208) is a handy guide to debugging from there.

### Stack Traces

By default, we can't trace a series of operations across different cycles of the event loop (ticks). To get around this have a look at [longjohn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/longjohn) (but not in production!).

### Memory Leaks

With Node.js we can have a server process expected to stay up for considerable time. What do you do if you think it has sprung some nasty leaks? Use [heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump) and Chrome DevTools to compare some snapshots and see what's changing.

---

For some useful articles, check out

- [RisingStack - Debugging Node.js Applications](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-debugging-tutorial/)
- [Excellent article by David Mark Clements of nearForm](http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/working-node-need-know/#more-3125)

If you feel like watching a video(s) then

- [Netflix JS Talks - Debugging Node.js in Production](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1YP8QP9gLA)
- [Interesting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaKU6VRmdag) from [the tracing working group](https://nodejs.org/en/about/working-groups/#tracing) on tracing and debugging node.js
- [Really informative 15-minute video on node-inspector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03qGA-GJXjI)

Whatever path you choose, just be sure you understand how you are debugging

[image]

> It is a painful thing
>   To look at your own trouble and know
>   That you yourself and no one else has made it
>
> *Sophocles, Ajax*

Answer (score 44):

[Theseus](https://github.com/adobe-research/theseus) is a project by Adobe research which lets you debug your Node.js code in their Open Source editor [Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets). It has some interesting features like real-time code coverage, retroactive inspection, asynchronous call tree.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this is pretty cool, still don't know what's Backtrace for tho

Comment: I'm currently loving Theseus, but I still have some problems where I need to set a breakpoint and trace through.
I'm currently having to kill my app, start node with --debug, trace trhough and then start the app with node-theseus.
Is it possible to use Theseus with breakpoints? I've tried searching around the GitHub page, StackOverflow and forums, but with no luck so far.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 27):

[Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/) 2012 or 2013 includes a debugger.  The overview [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNodejsToolsForVisualStudio.aspx) states "Node.js Tools for Visual Studio includes complete support for debugging node apps.". Being new to Node.js, but having a background in .NET, I've found this add in to be a great way to debug Node.js applications.

Answer (score 25):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has really nice Node.js debugging support. It is free, open source and cross-platform and runs on Linux, OS X and Windows.

You can even debug [grunt and gulp tasks](https://hansrwindhoff.wordpress.com/debugging-task-runner-tasks-like-gulp-with-visual-studio-code-editordebugger/), should you need to...

Comment: Starting from Visual Studio Code 8.0 the debugging support for OSX and Linux got really good.

Comment: After spending a whole evening getting node-inspector and strongloop to function under windows (Visual Studio Community, downgrade to npm 2, installing python, env variables, use cmd not babun / cygwin etc. etc.) and then playing with this for an hour, I have to say this is the best option at least in windows and possibly in general (if you don't have webstorn)

Answer (score 24):

I wrote a different approach to debug Node.js code which is stable and is extremely simple. It is available at https://github.com/s-a/iron-node.

[image]

An opensource cross-platform visual debugger.

Installation:

`npm install iron-node -g;`

Debug:

`iron-node yourscript.js;`

Answer (score 17):

I created a neat little tool called [pry.js](https://github.com/blainesch/pry.js) that can help you out.

Put a simple statement somewhere in your code, run your script normally and node will halt the current thread giving you access to all your variables and functions. View/edit/delete them at will!

```
var pry = require('pryjs')

class FizzBuzz

  run: ->
    for i in [1..100]
      output = ''
      eval(pry.it) // magic
      output += "Fizz" if i % 3 is 0
      output += "Buzz" if i % 5 is 0
      console.log output || i

  bar: ->
    10

fizz = new FizzBuzz()
fizz.run()
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using the [Atom IDE](https://atom.io/packages/node-debugger), you can install the `node-debugger` package.

Answer (score 16):

Using Chrome Version 67.0.3396.62(+)

1. Run node app

> node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 server.js(server js filename)

2. Browse your app in chrome e.g. "localhost:port"
3. Open DevTools.
4. Click the the node icon beside the responsive device icon.

[image]

There will be another DevTools window that will pop out specifically for debugging node app.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

There is built-in command line [debugger client](https://c9.io/) within Node.js. Cloud 9 IDE have also pretty nice (visual) [debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

Comment: Cloud 9 is way to go for me, especially gives freedom of code anywhere option without carrying my laptop.

Answer (score 11):

I put together a short [Node.js debugging primer](https://habd.as/node-js-debugging-primer/) on using the [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) for those who aren't sure where to get started.

Answer (score 10):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) will work for us in debugging.

Answer (score 9):

Use Webstorm! It's perfect for debugging Node.js applications. It has a built-in debugger. Check out the docs here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

Answer (score 8):

If you need a powerful logging library for Node.js, [Tracer https://github.com/baryon/tracer](https://github.com/baryon/tracer) is a better choice.

It outputs log messages with a timestamp, file name, method name, line number, path or call stack, support color console, and support database, file, stream transport easily. I am the author.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have node-inspector installed on your computer (if not, just type 'npm install -g node-inspector') you just have to run:

```
node-inspector & node --debug-brk scriptFileName.js
```

And paste the URI from the command line into a WebKit (Chrome / Safari) browser.

Comment: node-inspector was [already](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3944507/1269037) mentioned; maybe delete this answer?

Answer (score 8):

Just for completeness:

The [PyCharm 3.0 + Node.js Plugin offers an awesome development + run + debug experience](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#d91029e423).

Answer (score 8):

Start your node process with **--inspect** flag.

`node --inspect index.js`

and then Open `chrome://inspect` in chrome. Click the "Open dedicated DevTools for Node" link or install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj) chrome extension for easily opening chrome DevTools.

For more info refer to [this](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/) link

Answer (score 7):

There is the new open-source [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) project (as a Eclipse plugin or [Enide Studio](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nodeclipse/files/)):

[image]

Nodeclipse became #1 in [Eclipse Top 10 NEW Plugins for 2013](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/december/article2.php). It uses a modified [V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) debugger (from Google Chrome Developer Tools for Java).

Nodeclipse is free open-source software [released at the start of every month](http://www.nodeclipse.org/history).

Answer (score 6):

There are many possibilities...

- [node](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) includes a [debugging utility](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)
- [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)
- Code editors / IDEs (see debug instructions for one of the following)

  - [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/node-debugger),
  - [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging)
  - [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/running-and-debugging-node-js.html)
  - and more

Debug support is often implemented using the [v8 Debugging Protocol](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Debugging-Protocol) or the newer [Chrome Debugging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol).

Answer (score 5):

[IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/nodejs.html) works wonderfully for Node.js.

In addition, IntelliJ supports 'Code Assistance' well.

Answer (score 4):

The [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) IDE has had Node.js support since [version 8.1](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/):

> <...>
>
> ## New Feature Highlights
>
> ### Node.js Application Development
>
> - New Node.js project wizard
> - New Node.js Express wizard
> - Enhanced JavaScript Editor
> - New support for running Node.js applications
> - New support for debugging Node.js applications.
>
> <...>

Additional references:

1. [NetBeans Wiki / NewAndNoteworthyNB81](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81).
2. [Node.js Express App in NetBeans IDE, Geertjan-Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/express_js_in_netbeans_ide).

Answer (score 4):

Use this commands

```
DEBUG_LEVEL=all node file.js
DEBUG=* node file.js
node file.js --inspect
```

Answer (score 4):

ndb is an improved debugging experience for Node.js, enabled by Chrome DevTools

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb

Answer (score 3):

```
node-debug -p 8888 scriptFileName.js
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick-and-dirty way to debug small Node.js scripts with your favorite **browser debugger** would be to use **browserify**. Note that this approach doesn't work with any applications which require native I/O libraries, but it is good enough for most small scripts.

```
$ npm install -g browserify
```

Now move all your `var x = requires('x')` calls into a `requires.js` file and run:

```
$ browserify requires.js -s window -o bundle.js
```

(The downside here is that you either have to move or comment the `requires` in all your files.)

Include the `bundle.js` in an HTML file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Now load the file in your browser and press <kbd>F12</kbd> and viola: debug in browser.

Answer (score 3):

Another option not mentioned in other answers is using a tool called [Rookout](https://rookout.com/). It's used to debug and get data from both local and remote apps. We use it in our production environment to aggregate data to other services - saves us a lot of headaches and hardcoded logging

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding some links does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.

Answer (score 3):

This method is valid to **JS** also **Node js**. It is put `debugger` word that you want to check. When running your JS or Node js app **`open the inspect element`** in the browser. If reach that line execution will pause like the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My original response was couple of years ago pre visual studio.

So, Using  [GOOD](https://github.com/hapijs/good)  by hapi is  a great logging package but for debugging use [visual studio](https://code.visualstudio.com).

original response (some long time ago):
I would use [GOOD](https://github.com/hapijs/good) by Walmart Labs. It will do the job, and it's very flexible:

```
var hapi = require('hapi');
var good = require('good');
var server = hapi.createServer('localhost', 5000,{});
server.route({SOME ROUTE HERE});
server.start();

var options = {
subscribers: {
    'console':               ['ops', 'request', 'log', 'error'],
    'http://localhost/logs': ['log']
    }
};
server.pack.require('good', options, function (err) {

    if (!err) {
        console.log('Plugin loaded successfully');
    }
});
```

Comment: Good is **not** for debugging. Its a hapi js plugging to provide interaction with various events generated by the hapi server.

Comment: @shivam you are right I wrote this post almost 5 years ago (today Dec, 2018) If you need to debug a node app use vscode with debugger

Answer (score 2):

You may use pure Node.js and debug the application in the console if you wish.

For example let's create a dummy `debug.js` file that we want to debug and put breakpoints in it (`debugger` statement):

```js
let a = 5;
debugger;

a *= 2;
debugger;

let b = 10;
debugger;

let c = a + b;
debugger;

console.log(c);
```

Then you may run this file for debugging using `inspect` command:

```
node inspect debug.js
```

This will launch the debugger in the console and you'll se the output that is similar to:

```
< Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/6da25f21-63a0-480d-b128-83a792b516fc
< For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
< Debugger attached.
Break on start in debug.js:1
> 1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let a = 5;
  2 debugger;
  3
```

You may notice here that file execution has been stopped at first line. From this moment you may go through the file step by step using following commands (hot-keys):

- `cont` to continue,
- `next` to go to the next breakpoint,
- `in` to step in,
- `out` to step out
- `pause` to pause it

Let's type `cont` several times and see how we get from breakpoint to breakpoint:

```
debug> next
break in misc/debug.js:1
> 1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let a = 5;
  2 debugger;
  3
debug> next
break in misc/debug.js:2
  1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let a = 5;
> 2 debugger;
  3
  4 a *= 2;
debug> next
break in misc/debug.js:4
  2 debugger;
  3
> 4 a *= 2;
  5 debugger;
  6
```

What we may do now is we may check the variable values at this point by writing `repl` command. This will allow you to write variable name and see its value:

```
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> a
5
> b
undefined
> c
undefined
>
```

You may see that we have `a = 5` at this moment and `b` and `c` are undefined.

Of course for more complex debugging you may want to use some external tools (IDE, browser). You may read more [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

Comment: Tested in node.js v10.15.1. Any way to make it continue automatically to the first `debugger` without entering `c`?

Answer (score 2):

Enable VS Code preference ***Auto Attach*** from ***File -> Preferences -> Settings ->*** Search for ***Auto Attach*** and set it On, open the console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>) or from the menu ***Terminal -> New Terminal***, set a breakpoint in your code, type in the command

```
node --inspect <name of your file>
```

This will start the debugging and the VS Code will show the Debug menu.

Note: Auto Attach is also very helpful if you are working with node cluster worker threads.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to debug but I prefer and I use builtin debugger by node js.

**app.js file**

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

debugger;

if (err) throw err;

console.log(data); });
```

**command:** `node debug app.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can try-catch errors:

```
function yourFunc() {
  try {
      // YOUR CODE HERE
  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message + ", " + err.trace);
  }
}
```

Error message and error trace will give you infomation you need to identify and correct run-time bugs.

Answer (score 1):

#### With an IDE

In WebStorm you can just open your package.json file and run the scripts in DEBUG mode from there. Just click the green play-buttons on the side.

[image]

#### with --inspect

If you would debug an application directly from the CLI without an IDE, then you could run your script like `node index.js --inspect`. By default it will then listen on port 5858 allowing you to connect a debugger. Alternatively you can specify a different port with `--inspect=5858`.

#### with an environment variable

1. Create a script `myInspector.js` that looks like this:

```
let inspector = require("inspector");

// you could explicitly specify a port.
// or alternatively set it to 0 to get any available port.
const port = 0;
inspector.open(port, undefined, true);

// print the url which also reveals the port.
const url = inspector.url()
console.log(url);
```

2. Set an environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS="--require myInspector.js"`
3. Launch your script.

In fact, that's also how WebStorm injects the inspector. The beauty is that it works no matter which launcher you use. So you can just `npm run ...`, `node-ts ...` or even use some .sh/.bat file.

Answer (score 1):

Please try interesting way to debug Node.js applications (not only) using **Smart logs**

https://github.com/darky/the-most-convenient-debug

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways to debug Node.JS application as follows:

1) Install devtool and start application with it

```
npm install devtool -g --save
devtool server.js
```

this will open in chrome developer mode so you can put a debugger point and test.

2) debug with node-inspector

```
node-inspector
```

3) debug with --debug

```
node --debug app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Exclusive for VS code developers using node js. Enable inbuilt debug

file > preferences > settings > in search box type "autoattach" and set how debugger should attach [preferred onlyWithFlag]
[image: autoattach-enable]

say magic, and you should see

[image: autoattach-active]

run node program with --inspect you should vs code doing her job :)

Tip: you can also run without --inspect by enabling always filter