# IDE and Debugger for node.js

Tags: node.js, debugging, ide

I am going to start building project in node.js (was working in PHP before), What is the IDE, Debugger and Helping Tools for node.js, to help improvement while coding ?

Comment: WebStorm/PHPStorm supports debugging natively in their IDE: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/11/webstorm-your-node-app/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919977/what-ide-to-use-for-node-js-javascript

Comment: @AndersonGreen: this IS a duplicate of that question; however that question was "wisely" closed, so now we can't keep it updated.

Comment: @meagar: how about move this question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @JoelHandwell see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/node-js-ide-for-windows-and-linux

Answer (score 31):

There are several IDEs which support Node.js natively:

### Desktop-based IDEs

- [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) - popular and extremely powerful IDE for coding web applications. $100 for commercial license, $50 personal, $25 academic, free for open source developers upon application approval. Can also debug Meteor.JS applications.
- [Komodo IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919977/what-ide-to-use-for-node-js-javascript)
- [Cloud9 Local](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) - You can install a local copy of cloud9 on desktop as well and work on a local directory as workspace, follow the instructions [on github page](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9). *Be sure to disable incompatible plug-ins from config.* It provides proper debugging as well.

### Cloud-based IDEs

- [Cloud9 IDE](http://cloud9ide.com/) - cloud-based IDE with native support for development of Node.js applications including debugging and other features.
- [Koding](http://koding.com) Koding offers you a free rootable VM with Node. Also you can work on the same code with your friends.

Other than these two you can use almost any code editor/IDE which simplifies JavaScript based development in general (for example with syntax highlighting, autocompletion or similar stuff) and use node with its built-in V8 [debugger](http://vimeo.com/19465332).

Comment: How to use WebStorm to code in node.js ?

Comment: [SEE THIS](http://www.gridshore.nl/2011/03/16/first-steps-with-node-js/) - Conclusion: I tried WebStorm, but it does not have Node.js support.

Is that true ???

Comment: @Mark: there is link behind the "on the way" saying that they are "working it"

Comment: @Mark: Node.JS support is implemented in WebStorm: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/tag/node-js/

Comment: C9 is vaporware. You can create an account and hand over money (sometimes), but half the features are constantly broken. It has great promise and is worth watching though (same could be said for Adobe's new online IDE).

Comment: @MortenMertner This might have been true when you wrote it, but is certainly not true now... C9 is badass; can work with 40+ languages, push your changes directly to GitHub, Heroku, Azure, or FTP to a client server, has a built in bash/npm console, and a zillion other fully working features.... you might look at it again.

Answer (score 15):

Microsoft just launch a cross platform IDE "Visual Studio Code" in Windows, Ubuntu and MacOSX.  It could debug node.js.  [Check detail here.](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging)

Comment: For more information, this video shows breakpoint feature in Visual Studio Code. https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B881 I think VSC is the lightest yet powerful Node.js IDE across various OS plarforms.

Comment: And it's freeware!

Answer (score 8):

[Koding](http://koding.com) is another good choice. It comes preinstalled with Node.js, Vim and Emacs, has a great community of developers, among many other things. Another few notable features are:

1. Free virtual machine (VM) with Ubuntu, root access, apt-get, and many commonly used tools
2. Built-in Terminal with 256-color support
3. All languages, databases, and command-line tools are supported
4. Various file upload options such as Drag & Drop, Dropbox, Clone from Github, FTP and the ability to access them using SSH
5. Real-time code and terminal collaboration with integrated chat abilities

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio now supports full dev lifecycle for Node.js if you install the Node.js tools, linked below.

Allows for full debugging, intellisense, color coding, and more.

https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6):

vim and unix are your IDE.

If you want debugging then there is `node debug foo.js` or  [ndb](https://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/ndb) or [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) or use the V8 Debugger.

Comment: Can one step into/over calls in Node.js program within vim, without leaving the editor?

Comment: @DanDascalescu You can if you use vdebug, I've even got a little UI setup with unite.vim https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BnIau7KIMAA1R7c.png:large

Comment: @DanDascalescu try https://github.com/sidorares/node-vim-debugger

Answer (score 6):

Another option could be Netbeans with the NodeJS tools (even though I'm not using it anymore these days since I've been using JetBrains products now to be honest).

What it gives you:

- A Node project type
- Clickable stack traces in the output window
- A run with node action on Javascript files (and of course, the project)
- Integration with Node Package Manager (npm) and a slick little UI for adding libraries
- GUI for editing package.json files, and generating their standard contents
- Ability to store machine-specific command-line arguments (excluded from version control if you use NetBeans' version control).
- Ability to download Node's sources so the highlighted stack traces point somewhere

http://timboudreau.com/blog/read/NetBeans_Tools_for_Node_js

Also NetBeans 8.1 and 8.2 seem to have brought some features for Node.js developers (see [here](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/) and [here](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/)).

Comment: Yes but i think it lacks autocomplete and code documentation as it provides for PHP. I new to nodejs and feels some time difficulty when i don't see documentation for parameters available for any method and there description.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is a good IDE for JavaScript.

This page https://portawiki.abnoctus.com/view/NodeIDE.html

details mixing eclipseJS with the google v8 debugger and a few node specific plugins

http://code.abnoctus.com/publish/binaries/node-launcher/

To build an IDE with support for editing JS with syntax highlights and some degree of code completion, executing node from the IDE, debugging in the IDE, unit testing with nodeunit  and fetching dependencies via NPM.

Answer (score 4):

I've tested several IDE's to develop and run node apps. But I'm feeling very confortable with [Microsoft WebMatrix 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/). It's a nice lightweight and free IDE that you can run Node. There's some templates for [Express](http://expressjs.com) framework to get started. And you can run nodejs processes through IIS Express.

Answer (score 3):

[Nodeclipse](https://github.com/Nodeclipse) has chromedevtools fixed for [Node.js debugging](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse).

[Enide Studio 2014](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/) comes with Nodeclipse, JSHint-eclipse, AngularJS and more plugins

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Nodeclipse-1-debugging.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/enide-studio/Enide-Studio-2014.17-createServer.png))</sub>

http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm partial to Cloud9's IDE though they've had a few issues lately with various upgrades, and the growing pains of online systems can be an issue.

[WebStorm 4](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is another option, though I haven't tried it, I did try the plugin in WS3, which wasn't too bad.

From Microsoft (of all places) there's [WebMatrix 2](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) from Microsoft that seems to support Node.JS pretty well.  I have discovered that you can actually edit node based js files within the Visual Studio 2012 beta and get intellisense/autocomplete for node scripts probably  from webmatrix's developments.  I've been using node as a build step for CSS/JS processing, and it's been working well for me.

Aptana Studio and others seem to be scrambling to add proper node support.  Right now options are relatively limited, but getting better.

Answer (score 1):

What framework are you using for the frontend? If you're already familiar with Node, you might as well try the open-source and increasingly popular Meteor.JS framework. Check out [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com) for literally a one-click IDE for Meteor apps.

You get a virtual machine with MongoDB on it and the Meteor server. A sample project is already loaded, and you can edit the server and client HTML, JS and CSS files. The resulting app runs in the right pane. Makes playing with Meteor super, super easy.

Answer (score 0):

Node is a relatively new project so there is not widespread IDE support yet. However there actually is an online IDE called [Cloud9 IDE](http://cloud9ide.com/) that you might want to check out. Otherwise I suggest you use a local editor such as vim or emacs.

See [how-to-debug-node-js-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications) for more information on debugging.

Comment: Cloud9 boasts that you can deploy your apps directly from their IDE, I couldn't find any way to deploy my stuff directly. Maybe they meant deploying on github ?

Comment: The deployment options are limited to a few cloud hosts, and FTP... you can do push/pull requests from git/github as well.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub's programmable text editor [Atom](https://atom.io/) has node.js integration.

Comment: What does that mean exactly?  Does Atom have a Node.js debugger to be able to step through code?

Comment: The question asked was about an IDE and debugger and Atom is certainly an IDE for node.js.  As far as being able to step through code, no it does not support that but the user did not specifically ask that question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm going to just agree to disagree with you on the "Atom is an IDE" statement. They advertise it as a hackable text editor, and without a debugger, I don't think of something as an "integrated development environment". If I'm just missing something, you could always update your answer to include more information and details. If you have more knowledge about this and could make your answer longer than just one line, it would definitely help others. I ended up using node-inspector and sticking with SublimeText 3 instead. Good luck and thanks again!

Comment: Sublime text 3 + node debugger inside the text editor or atom + integrated node debugger would be something amazing. I'm still waiting for it to happen!

Comment: Actually Atom does have a [Nodejs debugger package](https://atom.io/packages/node-debugger) that allows step through debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft's https://code.visualstudio.com. Its awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's [Nuclide](http://nuclide.io/) has a number of IDE-esque features including dynamic typechecking (via [flow](http://flowtype.org/)), in-code linking, auto complete, etc. It's based on GitHub's Atom so you can pick and choose Nuclide packages as you see fit.

Answer (score -1):

WebStorm 3.0 does all this stuff.
It auto completes in a smart way, includes nice debugging and unit testing. It also include number of inspection for javascript, which is also pleasant.
Now RC version is available, but JetBrains assure that it'll be released soon.

Comment: WebStorm had already been proposed. Would be nice to delete this answers and save other readers some time :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I use IntelliJ's Webstorm: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm for it's advance auto-complete features and Node.js/NodeUnit templates.

Comment: WebStorm was already mentioned several times, please consider deleting this answer?