# how to determine source information of callback in v8

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, v8

Is it possible to determine the source information (file, line number, column number) of a callback in v8?

```
function foo(callback) {
    var x = callback();
    if (typeof x !== "string") {
        //hmmm, x is not as expected, I want to know more about the callback.
    }
}
```

Comment: Then adding Node.js tag might attract knowledgeable audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware that you can do this in JavaScript, but if you can debug it, it should show you the file/line etc..

I guess doing that would depend exactly on your setup and I've never done it myself - it looks like node (uses v8) has some sort of [support for that](http://vimeo.com/19465332) .

Might be useful?: [v8 DebuggerProtocol](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol)

Comment: I might indeed use this in the following way: if x is not as expected, first have a debugger statement and then call the same callback again.

Comment: Apparently, there's some support in IDEs too, like Cloud9 (web based). Not tried it to be honest but could be worth a shot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652972/ide-and-debugger-for-node-js

Answer (score 1):

[callsite](https://github.com/visionmedia/callsite) helps with this.

It exposes `__stack` global variable which can be used to get the stack trace. And `__line` which is the current line number.

Comment: I don't see how. Can you post an example?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if it can do what you want. What do you want exactly? To know what file the callback was defined and what line number?

Comment: yes, that's what I want. If it is necessary to hack the constructor of 'Function' to add the source info to all functions, then that would be okay, but I don't know how.

Comment: It's amazing this answer doesn't have more attention.