# Add sourceLocation property to a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, prototype, v8

as a follow up to the question [how-to-determine-source-information-of-callback-in-v8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871874/how-to-determine-source-information-of-callback-in-v8), I have the following question.

If I look at the properties of a function, I see that it has a name, a length etc. Would it be possible to automatically add a property to all functions by hacking the constructor of the 'Function' object? If so, how should this be done? I would like to add a property called 'source_location'

```
function foo() {
}

console.log(foo.name); //works out of the box
console.log(foo.source_location); //can I make this work?
```

Comment: but `console.log` shows source location already ?

Comment: does it? can you give an example?

Comment: [Chrome](http://gyazo.com/69282b23aa0e4fe96958a7120e9bd644.png) , [Opera](http://gyazo.com/d47e3e0848b613349ead9ece61278428.png), same with Firefox and IE9.

Comment: [`Function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) is non-standard but is definitely part of V8 so should be available to you.

Comment: That's not a solution to the question I asked. I want to know the source_location of a function. not a caller. In the example I gave, there isn't even a caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use v8's debugger object.

**Source**

```
// test.js

function bar() {
}

function foo() {
}

foo.source_location = debug.Debug.findFunctionSourceLocation(foo);

console.log(foo.name);
console.log(foo.source_location);
console.log(foo.source_location.script.name);
```

**Execute**

```
node --expose-debug-as=debug test.js
```

**Output**

```
foo 
{ script: {}, // script object 
  position: 106,
  line: 5,
  column: 12,
  start: 94,
  end: 110 }
/home/skomski/test.js
```

**References**

http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/debug-debugger.js#586