# Node IDE auto-complete and debugging

Tags: node.js, ide

What IDE's support node auto-complete and can attach to the node debugger? I have used Cloud9 which does work well for node, but since it is hosted on its own servers it cannot access my private network. I have also used eclipse but the autocomplete is not very effective.

We are building an html5 website using node, it would be nice to have a good experience for CSS and html editing as well.

Comment: Desktop based IDEs with autocompletion include [WebStorm and Koding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652972/ide-and-debugger-for-node-js)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) by JetBrains. You can [debug node](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html) in it and it has a nice autocomplete feature.

Comment: An up vote wasn't enough to do this justice, so I must comment as well. I used Netbeans for my first node project and then switched to WebStorm. It changed my life. WebStorm is awesome. I highly recommend this IDE. As well as the entire JetBrains IDE suite.

Comment: Its funny because I really want to ask what the best node ide, but those questions are too vague for stackoverflow.

Comment: @JustEngland: you're right, but [some questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652972/ide-and-debugger-for-node-js) survive sometimes

Comment: @JustEngland in my opinion, any question is worth asking; it's just stack exchange's small mindedness that makes them impose insane rules. they will learn that in time.

Answer (score 4):

Here best IDE for Node.js with **autocomplete** and debugger

1. Atom with stylish coding and hundred of plugin
   [image]
2. Brackets
3. Webstrom
4. Komodo
5. Eclips

Comment: please tell me which plug-in gives Brekets autocompllete to Node.js

Comment: Thank you for yourself is found https://github.com/Acconut/brackets-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I recently found [CodeLite](https://codelite.org/) supports **nodejs** debugging.
Autocomplete works well for certain modules, but somehow does not work for other modules, such as [Express](https://expressjs.com/).