# how do you debug a node.js app?

Tags: node.js

I am working on a node.js app, and occasionally it seems to freeze. I assume this is because the user code thread has frozen. It seems to happen after about 5 minutes of usage, but I have no idea why. Are there any tools that would let you know where it's become deadlocked? Apart from adding logging on every line.

Updated to add more information....

I've added some trace statements and have narrowed it down to the following code:

```
exports.addLocationToRoute = function(req, res) {
    console.log("27");
    console.log(req.body);

    var queryConfig = {
        text: "INSERT INTO route_locations (route_id, location_id, order_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);",
        values: [req.params.id, req.body.locationId, req.body.order]
    };

    pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
    console.log("28");
...
```

I see 27 output in trace, but not 28. Is there a way to see why it is frozen between those two points?

update 2:

I just tried to reproduce again and it's become frozen at a different point in the code, but at this point it is also calling

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug node.js applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I'm specifically asking about how to find where in the code it has become deadlocked.

Comment: That's like a whole other question now.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using JetBrains WebStorm IDE for my Javascript development. It has full Node support, meaning you can set breakpoints and trace your code. However, WebStorm isn't free.
You may also look at an older topic on Node debugging:
[How do I debug Node.js applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications)

There's an accepted answer about using [Chrome Development Tools](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/), but I'd rather followed more popular answer's way of using [node-inspector](http://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) for debugging.

Comment: Any JetBrains IDE should have the Node.js plugin.. I use IntelliJ and it does the same

Comment: So can you use that to pause once it has become frozen to find out where in the callstack it is? This doesn't work with the chrome dev tools

Comment: Yes, you can pause, not sure about call stack though. If there are no callbacks to be called, pausing won't lead you anywhere.
@j pimmel: yes, Idea is fine too, but it costs more.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put node into `--debug` mode and analyze it with [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector).

When the code locks on some place, you can pause the execution with the pause-button ( http://pix.am/LYZz/ ) and inspect the stack trace to find locks.

Comment: I have that set up, but how can you use it to find out where it's become locked? I don't want to add break points because it only happens once every about 5-10 minutes. Stepping through the code, it will take hours to reproduce.

Comment: Tell it to pause on exceptions, instead. Based on your update, though, it looks like the underlying PostgreSQL server is rejecting your connection (too many at once?) Why are you opening new connections on every query, rather than reusing the same connection over-and-over?

Comment: surely you must have one connection per request otherwise you could have two requests using the same connection at the same time?

Comment: Look at the [Evented API](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres). You create a query and get a query object, then have a callback executed on the results coming in. A single connection with multiple queries (that are queued in the order they're provided to PSQL). This is better than hammering PSQL with closing and opening connections that are only going to stress the server and possibly run into bugs on the number of connections open and being closed at the same time (like I suspect you have here).

Comment: Hmm, I don't disagree with you, but the documentation says that the callback style is prefered over the evented api

Comment: They can say it, but TCP handshakes can be costly, authentication (if any) on each connection is costly, and hammering a PSQL server in a way it wasn't really designed to handle (thousands of independent clients, rather than the usual one-client-per-db) aren't actions I'd recommend. I've never had a problem with PSQL or MongoDB using a single connection and event handlers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9065/discussion-between-dan-and-david-ellis)