# Testing javascript with Mocha - how can I use console.log to debug a test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am using the javascript test-runner "Mocha".

I have a test that is failing, so I would to debug it using `console.log`.

But when the tests are run, there is no output (only the test results from Mocha).
It seems like Mocha has captured and suppressed my `console.log` output!

How can I get Mocha to show my output? (at for tests that fail)?

**EDIT:**

Huge apologies! — `console.log` does work during tests!  I must have been expecting it to suppress the output, and I didn't properly check my own code.  Thanks for responding.
So... that being said... maybe it actually would be nice to suppress the output for tests that pass? hmm...

On a related note: I want to use `console.log` because I am having a lot of trouble trying to get the Eclipse debugger to connect to node.js.

Am I the only one who finds this tricky?  How do you guys debug node.js?  With a debugger, or with `console.log` statements?

Comment: Good deal! :)  Right now I'm still very much 'debugging' node via moca tests.  I do see a time in the near future when I might want to eval some of the options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications

Comment: I would suggest that you don't use Eclipse for Node.js, it really isn't the best environment to use IMO. JetBrains' WebStorm is a great Node.js IDE, although it costs money. If you're looking for free, I've really been liking the new Visual Studio Code, which has great built-in support for Node debugging and other things that make Node development nice.

Comment: @dsw88 - My experience with WebStorm is that it slowed way down once our file structure started getting large and deep. Reminded me of the old days with Java apps.

Comment: In addition to what @dsw88 wrote:
Use VS Code:
Insert a "debugger;" statement somewhere in your code. Start your test with the --inspect-brk option and use the VS Code debugging action "NodeJs attach". The debugger start at the first line in the mocha script and you'll have to press Resume once. The next time your "debugger;" statement is reached, you are good to go.

Comment: RE Suppress logs for passing tests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100760/mocha-hide-console-log-output-from-successful-tests

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What Mocha options are you using?

Maybe it is something to do with reporter (-R) or ui (-ui) being used?

```
console.log(msg);
```

works fine during my test runs, though sometimes mixed in a little goofy.  Presumably due to the async nature of the test run.

Here are the options (mocha.opts) I'm using:

```
--require should
-R spec
--ui bdd
```

Hmm..just tested without any mocha.opts and `console.log` still works.

Comment: where does log() actually lot TO?

Comment: HHHmmm with 9 upvotes, on where it actually logs TO?!? might someone help? I'm using webstorm, and I'm not seeing it in the Process Console or the Debugger Console of the debug window.

Comment: That depends on the reporter, but usually the output is logged to stdout of the process that calls mocha.

Answer (score 38):

If you are testing asynchronous code, you need to make sure to place `done()` in the callback of that asynchronous code. I had that issue when testing http requests to a REST API.

Answer (score 27):

You may have also put your `console.log` after an expectation that fails and is uncaught, so your log line never gets executed.

Comment: Yep, that was my issue, thanks for suggesting this. I moved the console logs to BEFORE the failing .expect, and they show now.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with `node.exe` programs like test output with `mocha`.

In my case, I solved it by removing some default "node.exe" alias.

I'm using [Git Bash for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)(2.29.2) and some default aliases are set from `/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh`,

```
  # show me alias related to 'node'
  $ alias|grep node
  alias node='winpty node.exe'`
```

To remove the alias, update `aliases.sh` or simply do

```
unalias node
```

I don't know why `winpty` has this side effect on `console.info` buffered output but with a direct `node.exe` use, I've no more stdout issue.

Answer (score -2):

Use the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) lib.

```
import debug from 'debug'
const log = debug('server');
```

Use it:

```
log('holi')
```

then run:

```
DEBUG=server npm test
```

And that's it!