# Is there a way to enable console.log while running mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, logging, mocha.js, yiewd

I'm using mocha along with yeiwd and chai to test a javascript web application. I'd like to see console logs from within the application  to help debug some tests.

When I run the tests from the comand line with `npm test` I don't see any console.log() output, only mocha output.

Is there a way to view logs created from within the application code?

Update - here is my package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^2.3.0",
    "chai-colors": "^1.0.0",
    "yiewd": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --harmony --timeout 0 tests/*/*.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm I don't use npm test often but just tried it and had no problem having my console.log print during the test. What happens when you run a mocha test directly? By running mocha testName.js from the command? Do you see anything there?

Comment: I can use console.log *within* my tests but not from within the application code

Comment: Yes console.log works within the application code for me, and it is indeed supposed to. Are you using any special command line arguments? See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666349/testing-javascript-with-mocha-how-can-i-use-console-log-to-debug-a-test

Comment: I'll update the question with my package.json

Comment: I can confirm that running your exact parameters in my test still shows the console.logs from within my application code on the terminal right there alongside my mocha logs. The only difference is I'm not running yiewd but I don't see how that would affect anything. 

Either way console.log is supposed to work in a mocha test by default, so there must be something stopping it in your environment somewhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming that

Comment: If there's actually a problem that needs solving, we're going to need a [mcve]. Otherwise, the only thing we can say is exactly what KJ3 said: "works for me."

Comment: Wish this had been answered

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour as me @developius ?

Comment: It's weird. I see it in some places, but not others. It's usually when I'm trying to log an error object from a callback (e.g. a mongoose query etc)

Comment: Anybody tried passing some `--verbose` or `--debug` flags to NPM, with `npm test -- --verbose`? That helped me on the [same issue when running Jest via NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190964/3088045).

Comment: [`--debug` seems supported](https://mochajs.org/#usage); it should be `npm test -- --verbose`. Give a try.