# No console.log to STDOUT when running "npm test" (jest)

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm, jestjs

From what I know `console.log()` should work without problem printing to the STDOUT of my console, when running a script.

But in my case I have NPM configured to run Jest when issuing `npm test` from the shell, and any `console.log()` inside the test files doesn't print anything on the screen.
I tried also to use `process.stdout.write()` but still I get no custom output when running `npm test`.

How am I supposed to debug stuff in my test scripts?
I can't figure out if it is a problem from Node, from NPM, or from Jest.
There's a [Jest issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441) that looks similar to mine but still I cannot solve and get to output a simple string; while there rest of Jest output is echoed as usual.

Anybody experienced a similar problem?

**EDIT 1:**
I tried running `npm test -- --runInBand` but the log doesn't appear.

#### Note

trying to run the command repeatedly like

`console.log('foo...');console.log('bar..');console.log('baz..');`

I can sometimes *see the log*, but this is then overwritten/hidden by the rest of the following Jest output.

Comment: I would like to know this too, it's very annoying, if it's of use to you, the thing I do presently is where I would have a console.log I instead write to a file.

Comment: @Countingstuff seems quite tricky. Take a look at the issues from the *Jest* repository that I've linked, to track what's going on (since 2 years; and in the last 2 hours ). Try the `--verbose` command option, it should help!! (please let us know if it works!) I also thought about writing to a file.... but then I told myself I'd rather spend my energies in trying to not surrender to it 

Comment: I use this command and the logs are being printed: `npm run test src/rentcafe.com/ -- --runInBand --verbose`

Comment: If you read you'd see I tried those already – There's a Github issue regarding the problem, linked in my answer; I suppose they resolved it and released a patched version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console.log statements output nothing at all in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695717/console-log-statements-output-nothing-at-all-in-jest)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the linked issue since the problem is going on since years...

There is [a pull request in the *alpha* release](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/6871) that is going to fix this problem. Looks like the last refining is being worked in the past few hours (see Github issue link).

However I found a solution that works for my simplest case:

- just run enabling *verbose* mode and the log will magically appear!

```
npm test -- --verbose=true
```

This **will not** fix in every case; maybe async/multi-thread/etc will still have problems (please report your experiences, so I can update the answer); fo    r example adding a `process.exit(1)` after the log will hide it again.

Trying to press `ctrl + c` before the `process.exit()` runs (with the right timing...) will show that the log is actually there and being overridden.

I will update the answer with news, but probably this will help others in starting with Node/NPM/Jest setups!

---

Jest's GitHub issue mention some useful details/suggestions:

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-713433790
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-724131782
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-586359238
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-611122871
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-623856169
- aaaand.... https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-649391333

Jest replaces the global `console` module; this apparently is the source of the issue. And also the fact that [Jest will set it to true automatically if you're running a single test. upside_down_face](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9205#issuecomment-555407216)

Answer (score 14):

This isn't clean, but I've had luck with it, hopefully it'll help you until a fix is published: log some extra `newline`s after the log that's getting overwritten:

```
console.log('I want to be seen!');
console.log('\n\n\n\n');
```

Comment: I find that you only need one newline, and it can be placed in the same string literal as the message.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it turns out that in my case, the problem was calling `process.exit(1)` immediately after writing to the console. When you do this during Jest tests, the output seems to be lost.

The (not-entirely-satisfying) workaround that I settled on is:

```js
console.warn('stuff I want to write to the console');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  setTimeout(() => process.exit(1), 1000);
} else {
  process.exit(1);
}
```

For this, the NODE_ENV environment variable would need to be set to `test` in your Jest setup script or elsewhere.