# logging function/objects name's in javascript inside of a function stack

Tags: javascript, debugging, logging, console

Learning JS is a bumpy road... I'd like to understand what happens inside my code, 
so `console.log();` seems to be my friend.

From time to time I don't even know where errors came from (or I might be just
too dumb) So I thought of better logging my app stack. I tried to find a answer for this 
simple *yet complicated problem*:

**How to do that?** Besides with `console.log()`

For example getting the **name** of a **function** (constructor) where the `console.log` is being called proved problematic:

```
function SomeFunction(argument1,argument2) {
    console.log(this+'> 01 message');
    console.log(this.name+'> 02 message');
    console.log(this.constructor+'> 03 message');
    console.log(this.constructor.name+'> 04 message');
    console.log(this.prototype+'> 05 message');
    console.log(this.constructor.method+'> 06 message');
}

SomeFunction.prototype.sayHello = function(} {
    console.log(this+'> 01 says Hello');
    console.log(this.name+'> 02 says Hello');
    console.log(this.constructor+'> 03 says Hello');
    // and so on... //
}
```

So. Which one is Correct? `SomeFunction.constructor.name` is working, 
but this syntax is quite long to use everytime, so something like

`var fn = this.constructor.name` makes sense, but thats just inefficient.

Can someone point me into the good practices direction, how do I squeeze
the right log info from my code?

**FYI**: I searched into several books about this simple topic, and neither one
says anything about it.

Comment: use breakpoints in the developer tools instead

Comment: sorry but this is not the answer i look for

Comment: I think you are left with the syntax (however verbose) the language and API provide you.. you can like you mention cast it to something else.. (fn) but why? these extra few characters will not break the bank for file size (and if they do then do what you originally suggest)

Comment: every quality browser I use provides a stack trace when errors are encountered. The only difficulty is when the error occurs in anonymous functions, which is solved by Joseph's suggestion. I think you just need to learn to love your debugger.

Comment: assume that I don't have a browser. I just like to know about any other methods that don't involve a browser and/or console.log ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications

Answer (score 0):

Use developer tools (F12, control-I) or [get firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and enjoy single-stepping thru your code, examining and altering variables, editing css. it will improve your javascript learning experience dramatically...