# How to debug node js app with breakpoints and everything?

Tags: debugging, node.js, v8, node-inspector

I've installed node-inspector just to find out that it doesn't support breakpoints :| What's the point in it at all, bearing in mind that on big part node code is asynchronous and you simply cannot follow it step by step?..

I'm definitely missing a point here...

Anyway to debug node code with breakpoints and everything?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications

Comment: I came here from there - breakpoints do not work in node-inspector and there is no answer to my question. Is there?

Comment: It does support breakpoints. I just doesn't 'remember' them when you referesh the inspector page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug Node.js applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications)

Comment: Debugging node.js applications has become much better these days. So this question and answers are probably not even actual anymore.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(For Node 8 and later)

Node.js has a built-in debugger. Normally you can turn on the debugger in two ways:

1. Start your Node.js app or script with the `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk` switch. For example:

   `$ node.js --inspect index.js`

(Note: `--inspect-brk` breaks before user code starts)

2. If for some reason you cannot start your Node.js app or script with the `--inspect` switch, you can still instruct the Node.js process to start listening for debugging messages by signalling it with SIGUSR1 (on Linux and OS X). For Node 8 and later it will activate the Inspector API, same as the --inspect switch

   `$ kill -sigusr1 23485`

(Note: you need to replace 23485 with your own Node.js process ID)

With the debugger turned on, you can open the Google Chrome browser, and type in the address bar `chrome://inspect`

Then you should see an entry  listed under "Remote Target". Go ahead and click "inspect".

Now you can set breakpoints and start debugging your code.

Reference:

1. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/
2. Related issue on stackoverflow:
   [Chrome Devtools Dedicated Node.js Inspector not stopping at breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53210907/2700356)

Comment: To do everything in the terminal, you need `node inspect` instead as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429798/895245 as of `v10.15.1`.

Comment: I've made a video which shows the inspect setup with Node.js (and TypeScript if needed): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bV-DHjmwuZ0

Answer (score 27):

yupp, I've successfully used node-inspector. If you want *permanent* breakpoints, simply insert `debugger;` in your code. See http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html.

Making node wait until a debugger is attached, using `node --inspect-brk script.js` (previously `node --debug-brk script.js`), can also be very helpful.

Comment: with debugger; it crashes: node(31848,0x7fff70e12cc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10010f690: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap

Comment: I've never seen that error, sorry. Is your app's process crashing, or is it node-inspector? Which versions are you running? Are you using any native node modules that could be crashing?

Comment: For later versions of Node.js, `--debug-brk` is deprecated. Use `--inspect-brk` instead.

Answer (score 10):

To debug a Node.js application, one can use the debugging built-in method:

(1) Insert `debugger;` statement where you want to insert a break point
(2) Run the file with command `$ node inspect <file name>`
(3) Use a key for example, `c` to continue to next break point

You can even debug values associated to variables at that break point by typing `repl`. For more information, Please check the [official guide.](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)

Comment: Tested on `v10.15.1`.

Comment: If you don't want to modify your code, you can use the function `setBreakpoint` or `sb` to set up a breakpoint, eg `setBreakpoint('script.js', 1)` (https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `nodemon` library? [it can be found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon).

For development purposes you could start the app running nodemon. I have this script:

`"dev": "nodemon --inspect src/index.js"`

It will break any time a `debugger` statement is reached in the code. To open the console where you can see the server code, open the console in chrome and click on the nodejs icon:[image]

It also helps you refreshing the server every time you save any file on the server.

Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate a bit here:

Set a debugger wherever you want the breakpoints to be and then run your code with node debug script.js/index.js

When the debugger stops at you breakpoint, you will need to repl to inspect the variables.

Comment: i want a breakpoint wherever an exception happens (let's say I don't know ahead of time where that will be). how do i do that?

Comment: you can instead of using REPL command add runtime watchers, just type for ex. `watch('count') ` watchers api will print the value when debugger stops in that function.