# Debugging WebAssembly with node

Tags: node.js, debugging, webassembly

Is is possible to debug a wasm module through node?

I am using vscode and compiling with `emcc -g4 --source-map-base`. Putting a breakpoint in the C source file is ineffective. Trying to debug with `node inspect`or `node --inspect` through Chrome doesn't allow me to use breakpoints either, although it is possible to debug wasm modules from regular web pages in Chrome.

I am using nodejs v10.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I managed to get something working. I installed:

- Node v11.4
- Chrome beta 71 (because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288608/6251476))

And launched the node process with `node --inspect`, for attaching the Chrome DevTools.

Moreover, in my code, instead of doing `WebAssembly.instantiate` in one shot (supplying directly the bitcode), I do it in two steps: `WebAssembly.compile` first, and then `WebAssembly.instantiate`. As soon as `compile` gets executed, there are some "wasm" sources being made available in the DevTools. This is the WebAssembly in `wast` text form, in which breakpoints can be set before it gets executed by `instantiate`.

But you can't debug from the original C-source files, Chrome DevTools only shows the decompiled wast yet. This feels like the stone age of debugging, but it is still possible to debug.

Edit 2020: This article https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/webassembly seems to indicate you should now be able to debug in devtools, from the original C source files. I did not try it, though.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

WebAssembly Source Maps is supported by both Firefox Developer Edition (in screenshot) and Chrome 71.

What you forgot is, to include a path to the source map. For example:

```
emcc -g4 --source-map-base http://localhost:8000/
```

Every source files path is prefixed with `http://localhost:8000/` with this option. So replace this with your source directory.

Comment: I did put a path (although I didn't mention it explicitly in the question) but I put a url with file://. I thought it was the way to go. Thanks, I'll try again.

Comment: @dim Yeah, I mean your source code must be transffered through HTTP/S just like your JS files. Make sure your web server can access your source code and you can access the files on the browsers.

Comment: The thing is, I have no web server currently. I'm using node.js directly on my local computer. So any HTTP URL wouldn't make sense. Of course, I can set up a small webserver just for that, but that would be annoying.