# node.js debugging with source line numbers

Tags: node.js, debugging

Similar questions has been asked, I went through 'how to debug node' threads, but
those are however either old or not about the problem i got.

**Problem:**

I'm writing some small tools in node.js stack - and my debugging experience is quite frustrating: when an exception is thrown, in many cases I get very annoying messages like the one here:

`TypeError: Bad argument`

wtf? it's neither verbose or useful - no source line number, no information in which file this exception was thrown.

**Question:**

How do I get my console to output usefull information when exceptions/errors are thrown and console.log function has something to say. would be great to have a simple console.log call where it actually puts a line number and maybe a file name where the message happens.

Comment: I don't know how to track the info you want on console but debugging is very easy with WebStorm IDE. I recommend it.

Comment: Use one of the debugging approaches from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641679/nodejs-a-step-by-step-debugger-for-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in nodejs i use this function to see error stack:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--stack` option to see stack traces. Such as `grunt task --stack`