# nodejs memory profiling

Tags: node.js, profiling

Need to profile node process. i've some memory leaks in production, after some days of running node process.

i've tried node-inspector + v8, but it doesn't work, in new version of node-inspector there is no Profile tab. and in old version when i start profiling error is fired and debugging stopped.

i've also tried nodetime.com, but it doesn't show what i need, also it takes too much memory, it's not for production.

i've also tried dtrace (http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/) but it doesn't give me necessary information.

---

so what information i need for profiling memory:
get live instances, instances count, size in memory, instance types

do u know how to get that information?

Comment: Nodetime uses V8's heap profiler to take heap snapshots. It might double memory usage when taking the snapshot. You should be careful with it in production. What could be helpful though is sending custom metrics to nodetime using metric() method and then watch historical trends. More memory related automatic metrics will be introduced in the next version.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use [look](https://github.com/baryshev/look) module. It based on [nodetime](https://github.com/nodetime/nodetime) but works locally.

Comment: Thanks! but nodetime wasn't useful for me, it didn't show necessary information for me.

Answer (score 5):

I've found [node-memwatch](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch) useful.

The downside is you have to embed it in your application and have a bit of code for it, but it's useful for checking the heap at various places to see how much it changed after you did something.

Comment: there is one big problem. it shows only heap, but i need to see same info for rss...

Comment: Which approach should I use to profile heap and see w/o modifying source code?