# How to measure peak memory usage for current node.js process

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to find the peak memory usage for current node.js process? Best would be platform independent, but else something in Linux only? No extra tools allowed like for example valgrind or whatever.

Comment: Not http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage ?

Comment: not only current, but like to measure peak.

Comment: found [node-memwatch](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch) from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864221/nodejs-memory-profiling). Seems like it could help you.

Answer (score 5):

You could take snapshots using the `process.memoryUsage()` method, and cache them.

[Node.js Docs for `process` module](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage)