# Compare 2 circular structure JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket

I need to compare 2 websocket connections on my nodejs webserver. i cant just use json.stringify because the objects are circular structure. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested at [How do I debug Node.js applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications) a great tool for debugging complex structures in node is to use node-inspector: https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector

Comment: Cant see how it helps to compare 2 objects?

Comment: Using it with console.log for your two objects should allow for manual comparison (I've done it before). Are you looking for more of a programmatic comparison? If so can you please provide some example code showing where your stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore.js includes a _.isEqual method that does this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
_.isEqual(obj1, obj2);
```

http://underscorejs.org/