# Comparing circular (self-referenced) objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am comparing two objects that contains values as `string`, `number`, `array` and `object`. To this point there is no problem. When I am trying to compare self-referenced objects I am getting the following error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Self-referenced objects should be considered equal if they are referenced to the same level of the other object. My question is how to implement it. Here is my code :

```
const equalsComplex = function(value, other) {
  // Get the value type
  const type = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);

  // If the two objects are not the same type, return false
  if (type !== Object.prototype.toString.call(other)) return false;

  // If items are not an object or array, return false
  if (['[object Array]', '[object Object]'].indexOf(type) < 0) return false;

  // Compare the length of the length of the two items
  const valueLen =
    type === '[object Array]' ? value.length : Object.keys(value).length;
  const otherLen =
    type === '[object Array]' ? other.length : Object.keys(other).length;
  if (valueLen !== otherLen) return false;

  // Compare two items
  const compare = function(item1, item2) {
    // Get the object type
    const itemType = Object.prototype.toString.call(item1);

    // If an object or array, compare recursively
    if (['[object Array]', '[object Object]'].indexOf(itemType) >= 0) {
      if (!equalsComplex(item1, item2)) return false;
    }

    // Otherwise, do a simple comparison
    else {
      // If the two items are not the same type, return false
      if (itemType !== Object.prototype.toString.call(item2)) return false;

      // Else if it's a function, convert to a string and compare
      // Otherwise, just compare
      if (itemType === '[object Function]') {
        if (item1.toString() !== item2.toString()) return false;
      } else {
        if (item1 !== item2) return false;
      }
    }
  };

  // Compare properties
  if (type === '[object Array]') {
    for (let i = 0; i < valueLen; i++) {
      if (compare(value[i], other[i]) === false) return false;
    }
  } else {
    for (let key in value) {
      if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (compare(value[key], other[key]) === false) return false;
      }
    }
  }

  // If nothing failed, return true
  return true;
};
const r = { a: 1 };
r.b = r;
const d = { a: 1 };
d.b = d;

console.log(
  equalsComplex(
    {
      a: 2,
      b: '2',
      c: false,
      g: [
        { a: { j: undefined } },
        { a: 2, b: '2', c: false, g: [{ a: { j: undefined } }] },
        r
      ]
    },
    {
      a: 2,
      b: '2',
      c: false,
      g: [
        { a: { j: undefined } },
        { a: 2, b: '2', c: false, g: [{ a: { j: undefined } }] },
        r
      ]
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: You could send a Set along of values you already handled / verified?

Comment: That will allow you to halt the infinite recursion, but will you be able to tell if the circular object is at the same place in both arguments?

Comment: @Icepickle I don't quite get it

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17121110/1491895) claims that the `_.isEqual()` function in underscore.js will do this. However, the documentation doesn't say so.

Comment: @Barmar I haven't read that much of the question yet  i was only checking the recursion part

Comment: @Barmar is there a way to implement it in plain JavaScript ?

Comment: Of course there is. Underscore.js is written in plain JavaScript, so look at how it does it.

Comment: @Barmar I never did it before. I will try to look it up .OMG ;)

Comment: What is actually the output you expect, `true` in the above case? Do you just want to know if your code has circular references? I am just asking, because the 2 parameters you are given are not really equal, they are just similar

Comment: @Icepickle I need true or false. I will adjust the input to get `true`

Comment: So, if I get it right, as soon as exactly part of your input is true, it should be true?

Comment: @Icepickle yes , as long as two object are equak it should return `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like @stevendesu's response. He addresses the problem of the circular structure well. I wrote up a solution using your code that might be helpful as well.

```
const equalsComplex = function(value, other, valueRefs, otherRefs) {
  valueRefs = valueRefs || [];
  otherRefs = otherRefs || [];

  // Get the value type
  const type = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);

  // If the two objects are not the same type, return false
  if (type !== Object.prototype.toString.call(other)) return false;

  // If items are not an object or array, return false
  if (['[object Array]', '[object Object]'].indexOf(type) < 0) return false;

  // We know that the items are objects or arrays, so let's check if we've seen this reference before.
  // If so, it's a circular reference so we know that the branches match. If both circular references
  // are in the same index of the list then they are equal.
  valueRefIndex = valueRefs.indexOf(value);
  otherRefIndex = otherRefs.indexOf(other);
  if (valueRefIndex == otherRefIndex && valueRefIndex >= 0) return true;
  // Add the references into the list
  valueRefs.push(value);
  otherRefs.push(other);

  // Compare the length of the length of the two items
  const valueLen =
    type === '[object Array]' ? value.length : Object.keys(value).length;
  const otherLen =
    type === '[object Array]' ? other.length : Object.keys(other).length;
  if (valueLen !== otherLen) return false;

  // Compare two items
  const compare = function(item1, item2) {
    // Get the object type
    const itemType = Object.prototype.toString.call(item1);

    // If an object or array, compare recursively
    if (['[object Array]', '[object Object]'].indexOf(itemType) >= 0) {
      if (!equalsComplex(item1, item2, valueRefs.slice(), otherRefs.slice())) return false;
    }

    // Otherwise, do a simple comparison
    else {
      // If the two items are not the same type, return false
      if (itemType !== Object.prototype.toString.call(item2)) return false;

      // Else if it's a function, convert to a string and compare
      // Otherwise, just compare
      if (itemType === '[object Function]') {
        if (item1.toString() !== item2.toString()) return false;
      } else {
        if (item1 !== item2) return false;
      }
    }
  };

  // Compare properties
  if (type === '[object Array]') {
    for (let i = 0; i < valueLen; i++) {
      if (compare(value[i], other[i]) === false) return false;
    }
  } else {
    for (let key in value) {
      if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (compare(value[key], other[key]) === false) return false;
      }
    }
  }

  // If nothing failed, return true
  return true;
};
const r = { a: 1 };
r.b = {c: r};
const d = { a: 1 };
d.b = {c: d};

console.log(
  equalsComplex(
    {
      a: 2,
      b: '2',
      c: false,
      g: [
        { a: { j: undefined } },
        { a: 2, b: '2', c: false, g: [{ a: { j: undefined } }] },
        r
      ]
    },
    {
      a: 2,
      b: '2',
      c: false,
      g: [
        { a: { j: undefined } },
        { a: 2, b: '2', c: false, g: [{ a: { j: undefined } }] },
        d
      ]
    }
  )
);
```

Basically, you keep track of the references to objects and arrays that you have seen so far in each branch (the slice() method makes a shallow copy of the array of references). Then, every time you see an object or an array you check your history of references to see if it's a circular reference. If so, you make sure both circular references point to the same part of the history (this is important because both circular references might point to different places in the object structures).

I would recommend using a library for this since I haven't deeply tested my code, but there's a simple solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution it helps a lot !

Answer (score 6):

### Before we begin

Is there a reason you aren't using an existing library like [deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal)? Sometimes it's easier to use code that's already written for you than to write it yourself

### Now fixing a few simple issues in the code

For starters, utilizing `Object.prototype.toString` to determine the type feels like a hack, and might risk bugs in the future if different browsers implement the `toString` method differently. If someone knows whether or not the `toString` method's return value is explicitly defined in the ECMAScript specification, please chime in. Otherwise, I would avoid this hack, because JavaScript provides a perfect alternative: `typeof` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Interestingly `typeof value` will return the same for both objects ***and*** arrays, because as far as ECMAScript is concerned, arrays are a subclass of objects. Therefore your later comparison for `[Object object]` and `[Object Array]` can be simplified to just checking the type for `object`

Once you start using `typeof value` instead of `Object.prototype.toString.apply(value)`, you will need a way to differentiate objects from arrays for comparison. For this purpose, you can use `Array.isArray`

### On to the meat of the problem

Now regarding self-references, the issue you're referring to is a ***cycle***. A simple cycle would be:

```
var a = {};
a.foo = a;
```

This creates the cycle: `a.foo.foo.foo.foo.foo.... == a`

There is a nice way to check if two references point to the same object in JavaScript, which is good for determining when equality is ***true***, but it won't help in the case when equality is ***false***. To check if two references point to the same object, just use the `==` operator! This returns `true` is the objects point to the exact same instance in memory. For instance:

```
var a = {foo: "bar"}
var b = {foo: "bar"}
var c = a;

a == b; // false
a == c; // true
b == c; // false
```

So you can trivially see if two references are the same by checking that `item1 == item2`

But when they ***don't*** equal, you will still do a `complexCompare`, which will dive into each self-reference, and will have the same stack overflow. To resolve this, you need a way to detect cycles. As with deep equality, [there are libraries for this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cycle), but for intellectual reasons we'll see if we can recreate them.

To do this, we need to remember ***every other object we've seen***, and compare with them as we recurse. A simple solution might look like:

```
var objectsWeveSeen = [];

function decycle(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
            for (var i = 0; i < objectsWeveSeen.length; i++) {
                if (objectsWeveSeen[i] == obj[key]) {
                    obj[key] = "CYCLE! -- originally seen at index " + i;
                }
            }
            objectsWeveSeen.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

(NOTE: This decycle function is destructive. It modifies the original object. Also, this decycle function isn't recursive, so it actually sucks. But it at least gives you the general idea and you can try to write your own, or look at how others have done it)

We could then pass an object to it like so:

```
var a = {foo: {}};
a.baz = a.foo;
console.log(decycle(a));
// Outputs: {foo: {}, baz: "CYCLE! -- originally seen at index 0"}
```

Since this object lacks cycles, you can now perform your complex comparison on it:

```
complexCompare(decycle(a));
```

Of course there are still some edge cases to consider. Are two `Date` objects equivalent if they reference the same time, but have different timezones? Does `null` equal `null`? And my simple decycle algorithm fails to account for a reference to the ***root*** object, it only remembers all ***keys*** that it has seen (although this should be simple for you to add if you think about it)

### A not-quite-perfect but working-on-it solution

I haven't written out a perfect deep-equals implementation for two reasons:

1. I feel like writing code is the best way to learn, not copying and pasting it from others
2. I'm sure there are edge cases I'm not thinking about (which is the reason you should use a battle-tested library like Lodash instead of writing your own code) and by admitting that this is an incomplete solution instead of selling it as what it isn't, you will be encouraged to go find someone who has written a more complete answer

```
function complexCompare(value, other) {
    var objectsWeveSeen = [];
    function nonDestructiveDecycle(obj) {
        var newObj = {};
        for (var key in obj) {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
            if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
                for (var i = 0; i < objectsWeveSeen.length; i++) {
                    if (objectsWeveSeen[i] == obj[key]) {
                        newObj[key] = "CYCLE! -- originally seen at index " + i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                objectsWeveSeen.push(obj[key]);
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    }

    var type = typeof value;
    if (type !== typeof other) return false;

    if (type !== "object") return value === other;

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        if (!Array.isArray(other)) return false;

        if (value.length !== other.length) return false;

        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (!complexCompare(value[i], other[i])) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // TODO: Handle other "object" types, like Date

    // Now we're dealing with JavaScript Objects...
    var decycledValue = nonDestructiveDecycle(value);
    var decycleOther = nonDestructiveDecycle(other);

    for (var key in value) {
        if (!complexCompare(decycledValue[key], decycleOther[key])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Update

In response to comments:

#### `==` versus `===`

`==` performs a "loose" comparison between two variables. For instance, `3 == "3"` will return true. `===` performs a "strict" comparison between two variables. So `3 === "3"` will return false. In our case, you can use whichever you prefer and there should be no difference in the outcome, because:

- `typeof` always returns a string. Therefore `typeof x == typeof y` is the exact same as `typeof x === typeof y`
- If you check that two variables are the same type **before** you compare their values, you should never run into one of the edge cases where `==` and `===` return different results. For instance, `0 == false` but `typeof 0 != typeof false` (`0` is a "number" and `false` is a "boolean")

I stuck with `==` for my examples because I felt like it would be more familiar to avoid any confusion between the two

#### `[]` versus `Set`

I took a look at using `Set` to re-write `decycle` and quickly ran into an issue. You can use `Set` to detect if there ***is*** a cycle, but you can't trivially use it to detect that two cycles are identical. Notice that in my `decycle` method that I replace a cycle with the string `CYCLE! -- originally seen at index X`. The reason for this "at index X" is because it tell you ***which*** object was referenced. Instead of just having "some object we've seen before", we have "THAT object that we've seen before". Now if two objects reference the same one, we can detect that (because the strings will be equal, having the same index). If two objects reference **different** ones, we will detect that as well (because the strings will not be equal)

There is, however, a problem with my solution. Consider the following:

```
var a = {};
a.foo = a;

var b = {};
b.foo = b;

var c = {};
c.foo = a;
```

In this case my code would claim `a` and `c` are equal (because they both reference the same object) but `a` and `b` are **not** (because even though they have the same values, same patterns, and same structures - they reference different objects)

A better solution may be to replace the "index" (a number representing the order in which we found the objects) with "path" (a string representing how to reach the object)

```
var objectsWeveSeen = []

function nonDestructiveRecursiveDecycle(obj, path) {
    var newObj = {};
    for (var key in obj) {
        var newPath = path + "." + key;
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
        if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
            for (var i = 0; i < objectsWeveSeen.length; i++) {
                if (objectsWeveSeen[i].obj == obj[key]) {
                    newObj[key] = "$ref:" + objectsWeveSeen[i].path;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (typeof newObj[key] != "string") {
                objectsWeveSeen.push({obj: obj[key], path: newPath});
                newObj[key] = nonDestructiveRecursiveDecycle(obj[key], newPath);
            }
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}

var decycledValue = nonDestructiveRecursiveDecycle(value, "@root");
```

Comment: Couldn't you include `Set` and `Array.isArray` in your answer? :) I like the depth of your answer, but I would also venture to use `===` versus `==`. And I think there is a small typo for `var b = {foo: bar]`

Comment: I actually haven't worked with `Set` before, so without doing some Googling I couldn't include it :) Although `Array.isArray` is definitely worth adding, because once you start using `typeof` to check for `object` you need a way to differentiate between arrays and objects before you compare them. I'll be sure to add that.

Comment: @stevendesu answering to your question regarding usage of the existing libraries like deep-equal. I need to implement it in plain JS

Comment: `objectsWeveSeen = new Set;`, then `objectsWeveSeen.add(someObj)` and `objectsWeveSeen.has(someObj)`. That will greatly reduce time complexity. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: @stevendesu `Object.prototype.toString` this hack is borrowed from MDN documentation  - section `Using toString() to detect object class`.  Your answer is a working solution . But to tell you the truth I have to digest it before full understanding. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

This package [@enio.ai/data-ferret](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@enio.ai/data-ferret) has a util method that supports data comparisons with circular reference support out-of-the-box.

First, install it `npm i @enio.ai/data-ferret`.
Then use it like so:

```
import { setConfig, isIdential, hasCircularReference } from '@enio.ai/data-ferret'
setConfig({ detectCircularReferences: true })
isIdential(a, b) // Returns boolean. Where a and b can contain circular reference
```

Full disclosure, I am the author of this package. I set out to solve this problem to scratch my own itch and decided to share it with the community. You can read the full specifications of the algorithm here https://github.com/enio-ireland/enio/blob/develop/packages/data-ferret/src/lib/isIdentical/isIdentical.spec.ts.