# Node: Can Passport be used to make Twitter API queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am just starting to learn Node, and Express (MEAN stack) and I am wondering, can PassportJS be used to make queries to the Twitter API v1.1, or is it used solely for authentication?

I've built the following code, but I am not getting anything desirable back from it (application crashes):

My Controller:

```
  /**
   * Module dependencies.
   */
  var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      async = require('async'),
      passport = require('passport'),
      TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy,
      _ = require('underscore');


  exports.auth = function(req, res, passport) {
        passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
            consumerKey: '7rTisA540o3BkQPRItqog',
            consumerSecret: 'u5f4xShik2GSypDu7pFuXpRlf23nZdS1CeZCMSXE',
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
          },
          function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
            console.log(token, tokenSecret, profile, done);
          }
        ));
  };
```

Routes:

```
// Twitter API
app.get('/twitter', twitter.auth);
```

When I hit Localhost:3000/twitter, I end up with the following message:

```
TypeError: Object function callbacks(err) {
      var fn = route.callbacks[i++];
      try {
        if ('route' == err) {
          nextRoute();
        } else if (err && fn) {
          if (fn.length < 4) return callbacks(err);
          fn(err, req, res, callbacks);
        } else if (fn) {
          if (fn.length < 4) return fn(req, res, callbacks);
          callbacks();
        } else {
          nextRoute(err);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        callbacks(err);
      }
    } has no method 'use'
    at exports.auth (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/app/controllers/twitter.js:12:16)
    at callbacks (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at Context.next (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Context.actions.pass (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:77:8)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/strategies/session.js:67:10)
    at attempt (/Users/nfento/Sites/mean-stack/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:243:16)
```

I'm completely new to this, I was hoping to get the auth token and then from there I can go an query the API, however, I can't get past the first step. Am I doing something wrong in my code, or am I using the Passport library incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like inside the `exports.auth` function, the `passport` parameter is not what you expect. You have cut a large part of the code in your app so it's not exactly clear how you've used that function elsewhere, but it seems that the parameter (the passport lib itself) is not passed correctly.

You can step through the code and examine what the value of that parameter is using a debugger and find the problem. See this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3944507/1801

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using the http://www.mean.io/ boilerplate, the code I have listed is the only code I've added to the project so far.