# Is there a way to print all function calls made during the lifetime of a script?

Tags: node.js, debugging, code-readability

Is there a way to print every function call that's made during the lifetime of a script in NodeJS? The current debugging tools seem to be focused on inspecting the state of the program at an exact point in time. What I'm really looking for is a historic backtrace of some sort. I imagine the output would have a tree-like structure similar to this:

- main

  - test2

    - test4
  - test3

    - test5

In this case, the progress of the script went like this: 
main -> test2 -> test4 -> test2 -> main -> test3 -> test5 -> test3 -> main

Comment: Lots of useful tools are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications/16512303