# Meteor 0.8.1.3 , 100% CPU usage issue

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

I am newbie to meteor. While using meteor 0.8.1.3 on ubuntu 12.04, when I run run a small app, CPU usage goes upto almost 100%. Can some one guide me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Install `htop` and have a look at StrongLoop for [Node.js profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications/16512303#16512303).

Answer (score 2):

Sign up for https://kadira.io and see what's causing all the CPU usage

Comment: I am confused. Kadira is showing 2-6 % usage of CPU. Whereas Ubuntu "SYSTEM MONITOR" continuously showing  CPU-1 90-100 % and CPU-2 also 90-100 %. Can some one guide me what is mismatch or wrong between these Kadira and SYSTEM MONITOR. When I stop "METEOR" app , CPU usage in SYSTEM MONITOR instantly comes down to almost 40-50%.