# Nodejs process hang, how could I debug it or collect dump?

Tags: node.js, debugging, process, dump, freeze

my nodejs process which was running at Linux, now it is hang and the CPU is 100%. Is there anyway I can do to debug it and find the reason? Do I need to collect dump and how? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful https://www.joyent.com/blog/mdb-and-node-js

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-to-debug-node-js-applications/16512303#16512303

Comment: Plus you can always run `strace`

Comment: @raidendev Can MDB be used in CentOS?

Comment: Should be, try `yum install mdbtools`

Comment: @raidendev that's a different package, it contains tools for working with MS Access databases

Answer (score 18):

There's an npm module called [why-is-node-running](https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running) that can give you info like:

```
There are 4 known handle(s) keeping the process running and 0 unknown
Known handles:

# Timer
/Users/maf/dev/node_modules/why-is-node-running/example.js:6  - setInterval(function () {}, 1000)
/Users/maf/dev/node_modules/why-is-node-running/example.js:10 - createServer()

# TCP
/Users/maf/dev/node_modules/why-is-node-running/example.js:7  - server.listen(0)
/Users/maf/dev/node_modules/why-is-node-running/example.js:10 - createServer()

# TCP
/Users/maf/dev/node_modules/why-is-node-running/example.js:7  - server.listen(0)
/Users/maf/dev/node_modules/why-is-node-running/example.js:11 - createServer()

# Timer
/Users/maf/dev/node_modules/why-is-node-running/example.js:13 - setTimeout(function () {
```

Comment: Excellent! Now I know what's in the way. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This tool helps with processes which have completed their work but not exited the vm. It does not help with infinite loops, which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

For me the why-is-node-running package was not very useful since I had an infinite while loop.
I wish there was a tool that will detect infinite loop all around the project.
What solve for me the issue was to manually reverse some versions of my project and to manually re-add the code I deleted, until I found out what cause my application to hangs, as I said, a infinite while loop.

Comment: Why there's no tool to detect infinite loops: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

I know this is old, but just posting because it's kinda interesting.