# is there a way to print the stacktrace of the current JS line when I ctrl+c in terminal?

Tags: javascript, trace, stack-trace, sigint

I want my javascript to print a stack trace when I force close, so that I know where a function is hanging for instance. Is there a way to do this? I run the code with Node, specifically `npx ts-node code.ts`. I imagine hijacking sigint might work, but then the console.trace would be from the sigint block and not the original code -- I am stuck making progress here.

Comment: How are you executing said JavaScript? With Node? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I've clarified that in the question :)

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165605/detecting-ctrlc-in-node-js help?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927233/nodejs-process-hang-how-could-i-debug-it-or-collect-dump and other similar

Comment: Have you tried something like `npx --node-arg=-trace-sigint ts-node code.ts`?

Comment: @esqew I get `npx: the --node-arg argument has been removed.`

Comment: @JohnTargaryen My apologies - forgot this feature was superseded by the near-equivalent `--node-options`. Have you tried something like *this*? `npx --node-options='-trace-sigint' ts-node code.ts`?

Comment: Yeah -- `--node-options='--trace-sigint'` works perfectly. Feel free to post an answer and claim the bounty (none of the other questions linked above have this solution; they are not duplicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Node runtime had the `--trace-sigint` argument added in May 2020 (as part of [`nodejs/node#29207`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/29207) for this very purpose.

When running through `npx`, its `--node-options` flag can be used to pass this option on to the runtime like so:

```
npx --node-options='--trace-sigint' ts-node code.ts
```

Comment: Turns out it only backtraces to a library function at `at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)`, and not to the actual function of the main code that calls the failed library function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the option `--trace-sigint`.

The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_trace_sigint) states simply that this "Prints a stack trace on SIGINT."

Complete command:

```
npx --node-options='-trace-sigint' ts-node code.ts
```