# How to differentiate between the main process and renderer process in Electron (atom shell)?

Tags: node.js, atom-editor, electron

How to differentiate between the main process and renderer process in Electron (atom shell)?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for here... can you provide a more in depth explanation of what you are looking for?

Comment: You might find this answer of mine helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29868175/352784. But it's really hard to understand what is the exact thing you're trying to find out, try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I think this question is clear enough though. Maybe it's because it has been improved?

Answer (score 27):

`var isRenderer = (process && process.type === 'renderer')`

Answer (score 0):

This [library](https://github.com/jprichardson/is-electron-renderer) might help you. It has simple API:

```
var isRenderer = require('is-electron-renderer')
console.log(isRenderer); //true or false
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if the high rated answer had been modified mistakenly. The correct logic should be:

`const isRenderer = typeof process === 'undefined' || !process || process.type === 'renderer'`