# Is there a way to access/modify the "Execution Context" of a Node module/function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand the scoping rules of Node/JavaScript, and from, for example, [Understanding Execution Context and Execution Stack in Javascript](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0), I think I understand the *principle* of how Execution Contexts work: the question is can you actually get access to them?

From an answer to the 2015 question [How can I get the execution context of a javascript function inside V8 engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30025045/2096401) (involving (ab)using `(new Error()).stack`), and the answer to the 2018 question [How can we get the execution context of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51979318/2096401), I suspect the answer is "no" but just in case things have changed: is it possible to access/modify the Execution Context of a Node module/function?

(*I'm very aware this screams either [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) or a desire to abuse Node/JavaScript: hopefully the **Background** section below will provide more context, and – if there's a different way of achieving what I want – that will work as well.*)

In a nutshell, I want to achieve something like:

```js
sharedVar = 1 ;
anotherModule.someFunction() ;
console.log( sharedVar ) ;     // Where 'sharedVar' has changed value
```

Having a function in a different module being able to change variables in its caller's scope *at will* seems the definition of "*A Dangerous Thing™*", so – if it's possible at all – I expect it would need to be more like:

```js
sharedVar = 1 ;
anotherModule.hereIsMyExecutionContext( SOMETHING ) ;
anotherModule.someFunction() ;
console.log( sharedVar ) ;     // Where 'sharedVar' has changed value
```

and `anotherModule` would be something like:

```js
let otherExecutionContext ;
function hereIsMyExecutionContext( anExecutionContext ) {
    otherExecutionContext = anExecutionContext ;
}
function someFunction() {
    //do something else
    otherExecutionContext.sharedVar = 42 ;
}
```

and the question becomes what (if anything) can I replace `SOMETHING` with?

#### Notes / Things That Don't Work (for me)

- *You shouldn't be trying to do this!* I realize what I'm trying to achieve isn't "clean" code. The use-case is very specific, where brevity (particularly in the code whose value I want changing) is paramount. It is not "production" code where the danger of forgotten, unexpected side-effects matters.
- *Returning a new value from the function*. In my real use-case, there would be several variables that I would like `someFunction()` to be able to alter. Having to do `{ var1, var2, ... varN } = anotherModule.someFunction()` would be both inconvenient and distracting (while the function might change some of these variables' values, it is not the main purpose of the function).
- *Have the variables members of `anotherModule`*. While using `anotherModule.sharedVar` would be the clean, encapsulated way of doing things, I'd really prefer not to have to use the module name every time: not only is it more typing, but it distracts from what the code that would be using these variables is really doing.
- *Use the global scope*. If I wasn't using `"use strict";`, it would be possible to have `sharedVar` on the global object and freely accessible by both bits of code. As I *am* using strict-mode (and don't want to change that), I'd need to use `global.sharedVar` which has the same "cumbersomeness" as attaching it to `anotherModule`.
- *Use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)*. It looks like using `import { sharedVar } from anotherModule` allows "live" sharing of the variables I want between the two modules. However, by using `import`, the module using the shared variable has to be an *ES Module* (not a *CommonJS Module*), and cannot be loaded dynamically using `require()` (as I also need it to be). Loading it dynamically the ESM way (using `import()` as a function returning a promise) appears to work, but repeated loadings come from a cache. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58153757/2096401) to [How to reimport module with ES6 import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56492656/2096401), there isn't a "clean" way of clearing that cache (*cf.* `delete require.cache[]` that works with *CommonJS* modules). *If there **is** a clean way of invalidating a cached ESM loaded through `import()`, please feel free to add an answer to that question (and a comment here, please), although the current [Node JS docs on ESMs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) don't mention one, so I'm not hopeful :-(*

#### Background

In early December, a random question on SO alerted me to the [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) website, where a different programming problem is revealed everyday, and I decided to have a go using Node. The first couple of problems I tackled using standalone JS files, at which point I realized that there was a lot of common code being copy-pasted between each file. In parallel with solving the puzzles, I decided to create a "framework" program to coordinate them, and to provide as much of the common code as possible. One goal in creating the framework was that the individual "solution" files should be as "lean" as possible: they should contain the absolute minimum code over that needed to solve the problem.

One of the features of the framework relevant to this question is that it reloads (currently using `require()`) the selected solution file each time, so that I can work on the solution without re-running the framework... this is why switching to `import` and *ES Modules* has drawbacks, as I cannot (cleanly) invalidate the cached solution module.

The other relevant feature is that the framework provides `aoc.print(...)` and `aoc.trace(...)` functions. These format and print their arguments: the first all the time; the second conditionally, depending on whether the solution is being run normally or in "trace" mode. The latter is little more than:

```js
function trace( ... ) {
    if( traceMode ) {
        print( ... )
    }
}
```

Each problem has two sets of inputs: an "example" input, for which expected answers are provided, and the "real" input (which tends to be larger and more involved). The framework would typically run the example input with tracing enabled (so I could check the "inner workings") and run the "real" input with tracing disabled (because it would produce too much output). For most problems, this was fine: the time "wasted" preparing the parameters for the call, and then making the call to `aoc.trace()` only to find there was nothing to do, was negligible. However, for one solution in particular (involving 10 million iterations), the difference was significant: nearly 30s when making the ignored trace; under a second if they calls were commented-out, or I "short-circuited" the trace-mode decision by using the following construct:

```js
TRACE && aoc.print( ... )
```

where `TRACE` is set to true/false as appropriate. My "problem" is that `TRACE` doesn't track the trace mode in the framework: I have to set it manually. I could, of course, use `aoc.traceMode && aoc.print( ... )`, but as discussed above, this is more to type than I'd like and makes the solution's code more "cluttered" than I'd ideally want (I freely admit these are somewhat trivial reasons...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the features of the framework relevant to this question is that it reloads the selected solution file each time

This is key. You should load not leave the loading, parsing and execution to `require`, where you cannot control it. Instead, load the file as text, do nefarious things to the code, then `eval`uate it.

The evaluation can be done with `eval`, `new Function`, the [`vm` module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html), or by messing with the module system.

The nefarious things I was referring to would most easily be prefixing the code by some "implicit imports", whether you do that by `require`, `import` or just `const TRACE = true;`. But you can also do any other kind of preprocessing, such as macro replacements, where you might simply remove lines that contain `trace(…);`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: it gives me something to ponder. Although I was "aware" of the steps behind `require()`, including the wrapping of the file's text in `function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname)`, it hadn't really crossed my mind to do those steps myself... For what I want, it's not as simple as prefixing the code with `const TRACE=true;` (I want the value in the loaded module to be able to change as it calls the framework), but I'm sure something "clever" can be done!

Comment: You can either wrap the whole code in `function exported(TRACE) { … }` and then call it multiple times with different values, or you can do multiple (different) transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're heading the wrong way. The Execution Context isn't meant to be accessible by the user code.

An option is to make a class and pass its instances around different modules for your purpose. JS objects exist in the heap and can be accessed anywhere as long as you have its reference, so you can control it at will.