# Visual Profiler for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, memory, profiler

I've tried [so](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) [many](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=webstorm%20node%20profiler&oq=webstorm%20node%20profiler&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.3272j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) [profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512303) for node I've lost count. I've never seen a profiler that gives you *this*:

[image: adobe scout]

This image shows second-by-second usage of CPU (top and center) and memory (bottom). I can click on a single "frame" (a dividend of a second) to see exactly which functions executed on that frame and what memory was allocated and deallocated (GC'd). This is [Adobe Scout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Scout) for Flash/AS3.

I need to find a *ghost* (a memory leak :), and I've successfully used the above interface hundreds of times to eliminate unwanted allocations and debug why memory doesn't get freed when it should.

How do I find which part of my app is allocating memory on a visual *timeline*? I need a timeline to see specifically which *part* of my app is allocating memory and why. Right now everything happens so fast I can't use the "objects currently in memory" panel to do anything useful. And [comparing "heap snapshots"](http://blog.yld.io/2015/08/10/debugging-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-walkthrough/) is harder than using a timeline. Web-based or app is fine. I use Windows 7.

Comment: I think you should ask "*How do I find which part of my app is allocating memory?*", and mention that you'd like to see a visual timeline of this; but asking "*Is there a visual profiler?*" is an off-topic tool request.

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks Bergi. SO mods have become super quick with their trigger fingers so its really nice of you to help me fit my question into the SO "format".

Answer (score 0):

I use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) as a process manager and they have a dashboard service [keymetrics](https://keymetrics.io/). You may have a look to see if match your need. :)

Comment: Its not free and I cannot run it on my local PC to debug locally. I must give these guys access to my production server, something that is a no-no from a security perspective.

Comment: However I can install pm2 (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) does this give my visual profiling too?

Comment: unfortunately, pm2 only have `pm2 monit` command(http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/monitoring/), which should be dull comparing to your requirement.