# How could I get the javascript thread stack from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dump, coredump

I am working with a performance issue of our application on NodeJS.

I am wondering if NodeJS has any mechanism to generate java-like core dump? I expect it would contain necessary information of thread / process status, and the javascript call stack printed within.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications?lq=1

Comment: or if you don't want/need all of node inspector you can use https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler to get a heap dump or CPU profile, which you can then import and read with chrome.

Comment: Thank you all above. As my issue is to find out what nodejs process is waiting for, because I expect the CPU should be 100% under stress workload, I guess maybe inspector or tracer could help some. Let me have a try.