# Very slow to load website using AWS ec2 and route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I got a problem about ec2 and route 53. I setup my website using node with keystonejs framework. It works fast in my local server and work well before I bind the domain name with route 53. But after I succeed binding domain name, it loads very slow and I use pindom to do speed test and find the following problem:
[View Pingdom website speed test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzXVv.png)

When it requests firstly, it has been waited for at least 8 seconds. Anyone know what's going wrong ? Why after I got this? I think it is not because of node js. My website is nexstartup.org( http://nexstartup.org)

Comment: It looks like you have a very long [Time To First Byte](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/ttfb.html). This is most likely due to the backend processing (DB calls etc.) required to build the page. The DNS lookup is not the issue (Route53).  You may want to [attach a profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications/16512303#16512303). Are you running a micro instance; is your DB on the same instance?

Comment: Your external files return relatively fast. This is most likely a problem with your node.js app.

Comment: what instance type are you running?

Comment: I am running Ec2. But before I bind dns, it works fast

Comment: This has nothing to do with Route53 the issue is with your app and instance type you are using.

Comment: I have solved....... Because the failure of npm install. Thank you guys