# How to watch variable on Node.js

Tags: node.js, variables, watch

My question is can I watch variables on node.js? I tried with watch.js and node-inspector but watch.js is duplicating watch methods and node-inspector cant watch variable live. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug Node.js applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications)