# IDLE Debugging : Structure contents

Tags: debugging, python-idle

Could someone tell me how I check the values of the fields inside a structure-type variable while debugging with IDLE?

I can see the name of the structure  in 'Locals' (I am within a function) but I don't seem to be able to type out the name in the shell window and examine the fields, unlike in MATLAB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug Node.js applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications)

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate of the Node.js question.  This question is probably not 'too broad' as it is fairly specific -- how to examine a local structurE.  But Sampath, you do need to provide more information.  A) give a specific example of a function with a local structure object.  What class is it?  B) Are you trying to debug with pdb, IDLE's GUI debugger, IDLE's Stack viewer, print statements, or interactive exploration in the Shell?  'Like in MATLAB' means nothing to me without having used MATLAB.