# How can I debug Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, phpstorm

I'm currently new to Node.js, as I had previous experience with PHP server before, I know that I can debug the server in PHPStorm that supports breakpoints and I can follow the process step by step.
I'm wondering if there is a similar tool for Node.js to perform such kind of debugging.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I googled "node phpstorm debug" and found [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/running-and-debugging-node-js.html). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of the [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) for these purposes-- let's you use the Chrome dev tools for debugging Node applications.

(From this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications).)

Comment: If the answer is a direct link to an SO question, then it's a dupe question.

Comment: Noted-- I'll make sure I know how to mark as duplicate for the future.  Sorry about that.

Comment: No biggie; wasn't trying to be mean.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about vscode. Here's more info https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging