# how to view Node.js with a debugger

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js application that I downloaded from github. I've been learning new languages by downloading tutorial code, reading the scripts, and using a debugger to view the script operation line by line (gdb, pdb, etc.). I'm trying to do the same for a node.js app, but I don't know how to go about debugging this code. Is there a known debugger or is this implementation even possible with this language?

Comment: Is that what you're asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications ?

Comment: You could try vscode. While I personally don't know how to set it up, it does come with a debugger. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging