# How to debug a react.js library

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I have been using react for about a year now and i recently wanted to delve into [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd). I've built plugins for vanilla js and jQuery in the past , but i am not to sure about how to go about building a react.js plugin or even debug it. i am more interested in debugging this plugin and seeing how it works more then anything , so how exactly do i go about doing it ?

Typically with a JS plugin, its mostly one file , so a console.log inside each function would give you a clear enough understanding of why and when a certain function is triggered , how would you go about doing the same with a react.js plugin ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by a "plugin" here. The notion that things are "mostly one file" may have been true 5-10 years ago, but that has not been the case for some time, unless it's something trivial. Debugging is the same as with anything else; set breakpoints. Note that this is quite a bit more difficult when you're dealing with transpiled JS, so you'd probably want a source map.

Comment: find the project on github (if it's there) and look at the un-transpiled source. you can always fork or clone the project locally and run the build/test commands as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks i kind of get the idea , i believe the right word to use was "component"

Comment: Good Question +1, checkout my answer!!

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow Thanks , i am looking for a more step by step breakdown about how would you go about debugging `react-beautiful-dnd` ... a bit more of a breakdown ! Thanks though, iám still trying to figure that out.

Comment: Unfortunately `react-beautiful-dnd` does not have much documentation and I think they are writing one. I will update my answer with few helpful links hoping that would help you.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: I have added how to debug `react-beautiful-dnd` step by step.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I think you should accept my answer now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to debug.

- [`node debug app.js`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/debugger.html)
- [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector)
- [`console`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#console)
- [`util`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/util.html)

Well, I use a lot of well place `console.log`, `console.dir` and `util.inspect` statements throughout my code and follow the logic that way.

---

**react-beautiful-dnd**

Unfortunately there is not much documentation and do-how thing for given topic. But here is what I found helpful. you can follow this link for **Quick start guide**: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/363

- The codesandbox examples from the docs:
  https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd#basic-usage-examples
- Sample Project: https://github.com/jacobwicks/rbdnd-2-list-example

[**All Examples**](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/)

**Basic usage examples**

We have created some basic examples on codesandbox for you to play with directly:

1. [Simple vertical list](https://codesandbox.io/s/k260nyxq9v)
2. [Simple horizontal list](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmrp44okvj)
3. [Simple DnD between two lists](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7ro2231o7)

---

**To Debug any Library:**

Here's how you can debug that library. This is the most basic method.

- Install it.
- Check what you are using and what you need to debug.
- Find that method in the node_modules.
- Check if that method has any declaration in the code.
- If yes put some console logs and see if they get printed on console.
- Then check console for your logs.
- Carry on the process of console logs until you get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You have to find library's function you want to debug in `node_module` and `console.log` from there. You may need to `console.log` the parsed file usually found in `node_module/plugin/lib` or `node_module/plugin/dist` rather then the `.jsx` file in `node_module/plugin/src`.

Answer (score 3):

[How do I debug Node.js applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications?rq=1).

This has quite a few answers on how you can go about debugging your react application.