# How to debug a Node.js server? The debugger skips my breakpoints! (Using VSCode)

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm trying to debug a Next.js app with a custom server which I normally run with a `dev` Yarn script that executes `node server.js`.

VSCode includes a Node.js debugging extension and [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging), which I've followed. I created a new Yarn script called `dev:debug` that runs `node --inspect server.js`, and the following configuration in launch.json:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Debug via Yarn",
  "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
  "runtimeArgs": ["dev:debug"],
  "port": 9229
}
```

However some breakpoints in modules imported by server.js are skipped and I'm not sure why. Other breakpoints in Next components do work when I load pages in my web app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

OK! Here's what's happening (and I'm posting all this to SO because I couldn't find the answer online):

When you build a Next.js app, you're writing BOTH the server app (node), AND the server-side web app (next), which are separate things! Additionally, you're also building a client-side app (React) on top of that. (If you're used to other platforms like PHP or Python web apps that use servers like the built-in ones, Apache, or NginX, this isn't obvious!)

Running `node --inspect server.js` tells the debugger to load the server and THEN start debugging your web app ONLY ("user code").

Solution: `node` CLI has a special `--inspect-brk` [option](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#command-line-options) to use when you also want to debug the code of the server itself! Yep, the solution is 4 more characters (`-brk`).

Comment: I found this out not so long ago. It may cause problem for anyone who tries to share a singleton service between custom server code and your next.js code (e.g. getServerSideProps) because it will be two different singleton instances. So you can only share stateless modules.

Comment: Thanks @dannyjee. I'm not doing much Node anymore so I'm not sure what that means but is there a better solution for those cases?

Comment: When you setup custom server, you'll do something like: 
const handler = nextApp.getRequestHandler()(req, res);

You can add a property to req object like so:

req.messageQueue = new MessageQueue(connectionString);
which will allow the next.js code to access the same instance of the MessageQueue class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that relates to my original question on VSCode debugger and breakpoints.