# Nodejs Mongoose | how to understand what a module function is doing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, node-modules

I want to see the Code that gets executed when `Customer.create` gets called but I don't know how I can analyse the code of the `mongoose` module.
So far i understand that `require('mongoose)` will lookup in the `node_modules` folder for the `mongoose` folder. This mongoose Folder has a `package.json` that reference with a `main` key to an `index.js` file inside the mongoose folder.

This is the `index.js` file:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = require('./lib/');
```

`require` will look in the `./lib/` folder for an `index.js`. This is a big file and i don't know how i can proceed in order to understand what the `create` function is doing.
How would an expert check what the create function is doing exactly?

```js
//app.js
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Customer = require('./models/Customer');

const start = async () => {
  const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
  try {
    const customer = await Customer.create([{ firstName: "john" }], { session: session });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

start();
```

```js
//Customer.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ firstName: { type: String } });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);
```

Comment: I would use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug Node.js applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answers. I use now a debugger in visual studio code and it works great.